# Generating dummy text programatically using TeX/LaTeX

Tags: programming, strings

As part of an attempt to debug another problem, I have a need for a TeX/LaTeX command that generates some dummy text in place. I know of [lipsum](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) and [blindtext](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/blindtext), but they are not what they want. What I have in mind is a command that takes the following arguments: a string (`s`) and integers (`k` and `n`), and produces `k` occurrences of `s` per line (no spaces) for `n` lines. I think this should be possible, even if one has to drop down to TeX to do it. After all, TeX is a text processing Turing complete programming language. Unfortunately, my knowledge of TeX could fit on a postage stamp with space left over, so I'm asking on this forum.

Comment: If you have no spaces between `s`, TeX cannot justify the line because there is nothing stretchable in it. Do you want the text left- or right-aligned? And what to do if the line overfills?

Comment: @Audrey: 1) Ok, lets allow spaces 2) left aligned, though can't one have it do whatever the local default is? I mean, when one normally writes text in a TeX document, one does not need to specify alignment 3) Dunno. let it wrap around?

Comment: If by "wrap around" you mean that the text should continue on the next line, then what is the purpose of initially having _k_ occurrences per line?

Comment: @Andrey: Well, the assumption is that the user could reduce k or the length of the string if necessary. To be clear, I mean the text should continue on the next line, and then break. SO you get one complete line of text on line 1, then the overflow text from line 1 on line2, then the second repeated line of text comes on line 3 and so on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest way IMHO to do it is to use `\foreach` provided by the `pgffor` package. There is also the lower level `\loop\ifnum\j<\k ... \repeat` loop which could also be used. However, you need to wrap the inner loop in a group to mask the inner `\repeat`.

As Andrey already stated there are the open question about how to handle line breaks exactly. I simply use a `\\` here, but you might need something else instead, dependent on the exact application. However, the principle usage of the loops is the same.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand\dummytext[3]{%
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#3} {%
        \foreach \k in {1,...,#2} {%
            #1%
        }%
        \\
    }%
}

\begin{document}


\dummytext{HelloWorld}{5}{10}% 10 lines of 5x 'HelloWorld'

\end{document}
```

Comment: That works, thanks. However, I think you need #3-1, not #3, and #2-1 not #2. Or starting with 1 will work. In your example you get 11 lines of 6x, not 10 lines of 5x.

Comment: Yes, indeed. My fault. It should be 1 of course not 0.

Answer (score 7):

And a Plain TeX-style solution using `\loop` … `\repeat`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dummy@line}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \@tempcnta=#2
    \loop\ifnum\@tempcnta>0
      #1\space
      \advance\@tempcnta by -1
    \repeat
  \endgroup}
\newcommand{\dummytext}[3]{%
  \begingroup
    \@tempcnta=#3
    \par\noindent
    \loop\ifnum\@tempcnta>0
      \dummy@line{#1}{#2}\\
      \advance\@tempcnta by -1
    \repeat
    \par
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\dummytext{abc}{3}{3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dumb question, but this function can be used in a LaTeX document even though it is plain TeX, right?

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: It _is_ a LaTeX document: try compiling it as usual. LaTeX includes much code from Plain TeX.

Comment: Yes, so it is. Sorry. I did say it was a dumb question...

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: You should not apologize for asking questions. Everyone does it in order to learn.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned already `blindtext`.
My first thought was, why not using it? You need only to redefine `\blindtext@text` to get your string. The other values are optional parameters for `\Blindtext`.

Unfortunately the missing spaces need also a redefiniton of `\blindtext`. If you allow spaces (see comments to your question), then just delete the redefiniton of `\blindtext`.

Below is an example.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
%Define text s
\renewcommand\blindtext@text{ab}
\renewcommand\blindtext@parstart{}%since blindtext version 2.0
%remove spaces
\renewcommand{\blindtext}[1][\value{blindtext}]{%
  \blind@checklanguage
  \blind@countxx=1 %
  \loop
    \blindtext@text%    here was a \
  \ifnum\blind@countxx<#1\advance\blind@countxx by 1 %
  \repeat
}
\makeatother

%5 lines
%7repetions
\Blindtext[5][7]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using LaTeX3 it's almost a one liner; the `\dummy_endline:` macro makes sure that a paragraph is terminated after each line; of course, if the copies of the string fill more than a line, they will be wrapped. If you don't care about `Underfull \hbox` messages, put `\linebreak` in place of `\dummy_endline:`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\dummy}{m m m}
  {
   \prg_replicate:nn { #3 }
     {
      \prg_replicate:nn { #2 } { #1 \hfill } \dummy_endline:
     }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \dummy_endline: 
  { { \parfillskip=0pt\par } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\dummy{HelloWorld!}{5}{10}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Still using TeX Live 2009, which doesn't seem to have `xparse`. Yes, I know 2009 is antediluvian.