# bug with page numbers when using soul package

Tags: page-numbering, debugging, soul

I recently ran into a curious bug when using the `soul` package. I
managed to boil it down to the following example. The problem is that
the page numbers get messed up. In the example below, they should be
1, 2 and 3. In fact, they are 1, 0 , and 1, in that order. It appears
(in some cases) that adding blank lines inside a `\hl` environment sometimes
causes this problem, and removing the blank lines fixes the
problem. As one can check, removing the blank line inside the `\hl{}`
fixes the problem in the example below. It is also possible to fix
the problem in other ways.

Anyway, now that I have discovered this, I can work around the problem
in my paper. However, I'm curious as to what is causing this,
so I thought I might as well post the question. I didn't try asking
the creator of`soul`, which I think is probably unmaintained. The last
update was a long time ago. This is with Debian squeeze, using TeX Live 2009 and `soul.sty` version 2.4.

I'm using the LaTex function `dummytext` below to generate dummy data
courtesy of the kind folks on this site, see [Generating dummy text
programatically using
TeX/LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25156/generating-dummy-text-programatically-using-tex-latex/)
The specific solution I'm using is by [Martin
Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25156/generating-dummy-text-programatically-using-tex-latex/25158#25158).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\newcommand\dummytext[3]{%
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#3} {%
        \foreach \k in {1,...,#2} {%
            #1%
        }%
        \\
    }%
}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\begin{document}
\dummytext{HelloWorld}{5}{52}

\dummytext{HelloWorld}{5}{17}
\hl{

x
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just as a note: making use of the `lipsum` or `blindtext` packages would make your example even simpler.

Comment: @Raphink: That is true. But `lipsum` at least didn't offer precise control on the number of lines, and I didn't want to have to guess what the right parameters were. I also didn't see a way to do specify the exact number of lines with `blindtext` but I didn't look carefully. If you want to suggest a working example using either of these, you can paste it somewhere, and I'll add it to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Problem

The problem appears to be the fact that [`soul`](https://ctan.org/pkg/soul) uses `\count0` as a local scratch register.
While it is, as a general rule, safe to use the even `\count`s locally (see .e.g [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88261/156366)), `\count0` is special because it holds the page number.
Using it in this way is fine *only* if there is zero chance of a page break being triggered within the scope where it is used (as described in [the same answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88261/156366)).

This is exactly what you see happening here.
While the page break does not occur within the underlined text itself, it is triggered by the paragraph break in the argument of `\hl`.
Until this paragraph break, TeX was still considering putting the first bit of highlighted text on the previous page.

### Fix

The problem is fixed by adding the following lines to your preamble.

```
\makeatletter %% <- make @ usable in command sequences
\newcount\SOUL@minus
\makeatother  %% <- revert @
```

This reserves a new count register for `soul` to use instead of the one it is using by default.

To solve the problem at the package level, the line

> ```
> \countdef\SOUL@minus\z@
> ```

in [`soul.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/soul/soul.dtx) would need to be replaced by (for instance)

> ```
> \newcount\SOUL@minus
> ```

There are a few other registers being used by `soul` for which the registration of a new register would probably also have been more appropriate. (See e.g. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48501/156366).)

I've created [an issue](https://github.com/drehscheibe/soul/issues/2) on the `soul` github page, but it appears to be inactive.

### Demonstration

The page numbers in the document below are correct with the aforementioned fix in place.
If you remove them, however, the page number is reset to 0 just like in your example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newcount\SOUL@minus %% <- without this line the page number would be reset to 0
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Blindtext[4]

\blindtext
\hl{Closing words

New paragraph!}

\end{document}
```

This is the bottom of the first page of the output:

[image: output]

This is what it would've been without this addition to the preamble:

[image: what could've been]

Comment: It seems that `soulpos` also has the same [problem](https://github.com/jbezos/soulpos/issues/3). Sadly, it did not use `count0` as I observed. Any idea how to solve it on `soulpos`?

Answer (score 6):

Not so much an answer as a simplification of the question to, hopefully, focus on the problem (a long, formatted comment?) and suggest two possible ways to avoid it.

The same behaviour as seen by the OP is apparent with `\st` instead of `\hl`. Using the `ulem` package and `\sout` instead of `soul` and `sl` produces an error about the end of paragraph within the scope of `\sout` (**! Paragraph ended before \UL@word was complete.**). Removing the end of paragraph from within the braces lets `ulem` proceed and produce a result with correct page numbers. However, with this same paragraph break removed, using `soul` also produces the correct page numbering. Perhaps then `soul` is proceeding when the correct, or better, action would be to flag an error and stop, as `ulem` appears to do?

To demonstrate this the following simpler example also produces incorrect page numbering:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[8]

\blindtext[8]
\hl{

x
}
\end{document}
```

whereas

```
...

\blindtext[8]

\hl{
x
}
\end{document}
```

does not.

This problem appears to be then that `soul` allows a paragraph break within its argument but fails to process it safely or to stop and throw an error.

**The solution would appear to be either**

(*a*) modify `soul` to identify the problem and stop with an appropriate error message.

or

(*b*) do not put paragraph breaks within arguments to `soul` commands.

**Edit: additional observations**

The page numbering disruption seems to happen when the start of the paragraph containing the `soul` formatting command with an argument that includes a paragraph break is on a different page from the start of the requested formatting. The page number where the paragraph starts is set to 0 and counts up from there. In the example above, deleting one of the `\blindtext` lines in the above example and its accompanying paragraph break makes the first page show number 0 and the subsequent ones to count correctly.

This perhaps fits with `soul`'s documentation stating that "the complex engine, which has to read and inspect every character before it can hand it over to TEX’s paragraph builder" (section 2.2) and the hint in the documentation's introduction that "there are several possibilities to emphasize parts of a paragraph" (section 1).

Various cases can be seen in the example below by setting the first `\blindtext` argument to 8 (page nos. 1,2,3,4), 9 (page nos. 1,0,1,2) and then 10 (page nos. 1,2,3,4).

```
\documentclass[10pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[9]

\blindtext
\hl{

x
}

\blindtext[6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I got tired to `soul`'s bugs so switched to the `changes` package, which seems to be less buggy, and actually maintained! I noticed that the `changes` package does not like blank lines between paragraphs either, but it actually produces a comprehensible error. `{\ifthenelse {\boolean {Changes@AuthorPositionLeft}}{\ifthenelse {\equal \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@textcolor was complete.` and auctex shows also `--- HELP --- A blank line occurred in a command argument that shouldn't contain one. You probably forgot the right brace at the end of an argument.`

Comment: Is there some simple explanation for why neither `soul` nor `changes` accept blank lines in these macro arguments?