# soul: broken highlighting with xcolor when using \selectcolormodel

Tags: color, highlighting, soul

I try to highlight text using the `soul` package.
But I experience problems if I use it in combinations with the `xcolor`
command `selectcolormodel`, only spaces are highlighted as shown in the MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\selectcolormodel{rgb}

\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

Please, highlight \hl{this small text}.

\end{document}
```

Output: [image: soul output]

Comment: Thanks, I had this problem with just standard `\usepackage{xcolor}`.  The top answer fixed it.

Comment: It seems to me that the issue no longer exists as of today's TeX Live. Can you confirm?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Edit

The problem has been resolved. With soul 2023-02-18 v3.0 the fix is no longer needed.

### Old answer

The source of the problem is that both `xcolor` and `soul` use `\dimen@` as a temporary register. And `soul` uses it at a place where it can't be sure that other commands temper around with this dimen. You can redefine the internal soul command, or you can use `\convertcolorsUfalse` so that `xcolor` no longer recalculate color at usage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\selectcolormodel{rgb}
%\convertcolorsUfalse
\usepackage{soul}


\makeatletter
\newdimen\SOUL@dimen %new
\def\SOUL@ulunderline#1{{%
    \setbox\z@\hbox{#1}%
    %\dimen@=\wd\z@
    \SOUL@dimen=\wd\z@ %new
    \dimen@i=\SOUL@uloverlap
    \advance\SOUL@dimen2\dimen@i %\dimen@ exchanged too
    \rlap{%
        \null
        \kern-\dimen@i
        %\SOUL@ulcolor{\SOUL@ulleaders\hskip\dimen@}%
        \SOUL@ulcolor{\SOUL@ulleaders\hskip\SOUL@dimen}% new
    }%
    \unhcopy\z@
}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

please, highlight \hl{this small text}.

\end{document}
```

If you don't want to copy the definition from `soul.sty`, here's a way to patch the command:

```
\usepackage{soul}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\SOUL@ulunderline}{\dimen@}{\SOUL@dimen}{}{}
\patchcmd{\SOUL@ulunderline}{\dimen@}{\SOUL@dimen}{}{}
\patchcmd{\SOUL@ulunderline}{\dimen@}{\SOUL@dimen}{}{}
\newdimen\SOUL@dimen
\makeatother
```

This will work even if the `soul` package is updated (because the patch won't succeed).

Comment: Shouldn't `\SOUL@dimen` go also after `\advance`?

Comment: Great solution! thx :)

Comment: @egreg Yes I have corrected it (I had read `\dimen@2` as a name instead of `\dimen@` +  `2\dimen@i`.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've added a version with `\patchcmd`.

Comment: This should probably go to Melchior Franz, the soul maintainer.

Comment: Since I'm still experiencing the same issue 4 years later I sense this hasn't been fixed in the package.  But this fix worked.

Comment: It seems to me that the issue presented in the MWE no longer exists as of today's TeX Live. Would your redefinition of `\SOUL@ulunderline` break anything? Is it still necessary for anything or can we get rid of it in our preambles?

Comment: @AlMa0 the patch is no longer needed, we uploaded a corrected version. It should do harm if you redefine it, as the new definition is the same.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks! If the new definition in the updated soul.sty is the same as your redefinition above, you probably wish to say “It should NOT do harm …”, don't you?

Comment: @AlMa0 yes, sorry sometimes the not disappear when I time too fast.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

My solution is just to avoid `soul` package. `soul` package is very fragile and may be problematic in many situations. I would use more robust [`ulem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ulem) package to define a new `\hl` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % use normalem to protect \emph
\newcommand\hl{\bgroup\markoverwith
  {\textcolor{yellow}{\rule[-.5ex]{2pt}{2.5ex}}}\ULon}

\begin{document}
This is a test \hl{for highlighting} text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting alternative! But I was wondering why some of my highlighted texts were underlined too. Found the solution in the ulem code. With `\normalem` it looks as I expected. ;)

Comment: This is really not a good solution. Please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254333