# Create box around text without creating a paragraph and with line breaking

Tags: boxes, framed, mdframed

I want to draw a box (no rounded corners, keep it simple ^^) around one or multiple words. There are two special things: 1) the box should support line break and 2) the box should not cover multiple lines. I added a figure to make my requirements more clear. I tested `fbox` and all its derivates, but all of them create a paragraph for the framed word. Thank you!

[image: Illustrative example]

Comment: Do you mean linebreaking within the box or such, that the words appear in a new 'box' in the next line?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A variation of [`this answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52336/3954) to [Highlighting arbitrary chunks of text connected to quotes in margins - Can this be done in TeX/LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49832/3954) . The boxed text can spann multiple lines, and hyphenation is allowed but no page breaks are allowed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

% The following code contains a variation of the great code by Antal S-Z
% in his answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6029/3954
%in TeX.SX

\newlength\LineWidth
\setlength\LineWidth{0.4pt}

\colorlet{HLcolor}{black}
\sethlcolor{HLcolor!20}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\defhighlighter}[3][]{%
  \tikzset{every highlighter/.style={color=white, fill opacity=#3, text opacity=1,#1}}%
}

\defhighlighter{HLcolor!20}{0}

\newcommand\highlight@DoHighlight{%
  \fill [outer sep = -15pt, inner sep = 0pt, decorate
        , every highlighter, this highlighter,draw=none]
        ($(begin highlight)+(0,8pt)$) rectangle ($(end highlight)+(0,-2pt)$) ;
  \draw[HLcolor,line width=\LineWidth]  ($(begin highlight)+(0,-2pt)$) -- ($(end highlight)+(0,-2pt)$) ;
  \draw[HLcolor,line width=\LineWidth]  ($(begin highlight)+(0,8pt)$) -- ($(end highlight)+(0,8pt)$) ;
}

\newcommand{\highlight@BeginHighlight}{
  \coordinate (begin highlight) at (0,0) ;
}

\newcommand{\highlight@EndHighlight}{
  \coordinate (end highlight) at (0,0) ;
}

\newdimen\highlight@previous
\newdimen\highlight@current

\DeclareRobustCommand*\highlight[1][]{%
  \tikzset{this highlighter/.style={#1}}%
  \SOUL@setup
  %
  \def\SOUL@preamble{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
      \highlight@BeginHighlight
      \draw[HLcolor,line width=\LineWidth]  ($(begin highlight)+(0,-2pt)+(0,-0.5\pgflinewidth)$) -- ($(begin highlight)+(0,8pt)+(0,0.5\pgflinewidth)$) ;
      \highlight@EndHighlight
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
  %
  \def\SOUL@postamble{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
      \highlight@EndHighlight
      \highlight@DoHighlight
      \draw[HLcolor,line width=\LineWidth]  ($(end highlight)+(0,-2pt)+(0,-0.5\pgflinewidth)$) -- ($(end highlight)+(0,8pt)+(0,0.5\pgflinewidth)$) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
  %
  \def\SOUL@everyhyphen{%
    \discretionary{%
      \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@hyphkern
      \SOUL@sethyphenchar
      \tikz[overlay, remember picture] \highlight@EndHighlight ;%
    }{%
    }{%
      \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
    }%
  }%
  %
  \def\SOUL@everyexhyphen##1{%
    \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@hyphkern
    \hbox{##1}%
    \discretionary{%
      \tikz[overlay, remember picture] \highlight@EndHighlight ;%
    }{%
    }{%
      \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
    }%
  }%
  %
  \def\SOUL@everysyllable{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
      \path let \p0 = (begin highlight), \p1 = (0,0) in \pgfextra
        \global\highlight@previous=\y0
        \global\highlight@current =\y1
      \endpgfextra (0,0) ;
      \ifdim\highlight@current < \highlight@previous
        \highlight@DoHighlight
        \highlight@BeginHighlight
      \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \the\SOUL@syllable
    \tikz[overlay, remember picture] \highlight@EndHighlight ;%
  }%
  \SOUL@
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\MarkText[1]{\highlight{#1}}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. \MarkText{Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.} Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus
eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur-
abitur auctor semper nulla. \MarkText{Donec varius orci} eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue
eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
rutrum.

Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi
auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna,
vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse
ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. \MarkText{Cum sociis natoque penatibus et
magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.} Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Simply use `\MarkText{text...}`; the thicknes of the rules used for the frame can be changed using `\LineWidth` (default value=`0.4pt`).

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I up voted also the mentioned answer!

Comment: Nice, but it breaks in interesting ways with text that contains math elements like "`the field $F$`".

Comment: @JoeCorneli I did some tests using in-line math and the highlighting worked as expected without breaking. Could you please give an example in which the code breaks so I can test it?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina The issue seems to have to do with shifting line boundaries not with the specific content after all.  Rerunning `pdflatex` fixes the problem.  To replicate, try entering long made-up words in front of one of the boxes :-)

Comment: @JoeCorneli Ah, if rerunning pdflatex fixes the problem, then it's not really a problem. Since `overlay,remember picture` is used, some internal calculations are performed on the first run to find the proper coordinates, so the code needs at least two runs to stabilize.

Comment: Is there any way to add a bit of padding to this command? Thank you so much.