# Box highlighting of text with rounded corners (soul-based)

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, soul

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164431/21440) it is an excellent solution from Gonzalo Medina.
Could somebody help me to make it with nice small rounded courners?

Comment: That's a `soul` problem, I think, not a `TikZ` problem.

Comment: I am not sure about what problem you are talking about. I ask about extending the second part of the answer mentioned in my question.

Comment: The answer you linked to relies on the `soul` macro `\hl` for highlighting.  Try doing `\hl{some text}` in that document and you'll see what I mean. My point is that the problem is how `\hl` works more than the "second part" (? is that the `\MarkText` macro?) or any other part. So: you can't (easily) use TikZ/PGF to modify the underlying `\hl` macro since the former is parasitic upon the latter.

Comment: I changed the link, see the update please, I do not care about notes, I am talking about highlighting specifically. Does it make sense now? Is it possible to add rounded corners to this one? Or do you know any other solution that does the job?

Comment: It is the same problem as @jon mentioned before, I think. It is really how `soul` does the highlighting. Rounding corners is easy in TikZ/PGF but that's not very much help here, I don't think. Note that if you really wanted a box with rounded corners (in the ordinary sense of 'box' - not TeX's), that would be different. But highlighting text is a bit of a hack, at least with (pdf)TeX, as far as I can make out.

Comment: Thak you for the clarification.This is sad.

Answer (score 3):

This is another approach (thus another answer) to this. It's an application of the [answer to Cool Text Highlighting in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429389/105447).

This approach has the advantages of allowing page breaks, and also more flexibility on the corner radius. There are some limitations too, especially that the decoration's settings are done globally (full discussion at the aforementioned answer).

The result is:

[image]

And the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,DIV=8]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,decorations.pathmorphing}


\colorlet{tdcolor}{gray!50}

\newlength{\LineWidth}
\setlength{\LineWidth}{0.7pt}

\newlength{\CornerRadius}
\setlength{\CornerRadius}{5pt}

\newlength{\BorderDispl}
\setlength{\BorderDispl}{2pt}

\makeatletter

\newlength{\txtdec@depth}
\setlength{\txtdec@depth}{.45ex}
\newlength{\txtdec@height}
\setlength{\txtdec@height}{\f@size pt} % sensible default

\newcounter{txtdec@hyphmark}
\newcounter{txtdec@decormark}
\newcounter{txtdec@hyphdraw}
\setcounter{txtdec@hyphdraw}{1}
\newcounter{txtdec@decordraw}
\setcounter{txtdec@decordraw}{1}

\newcounter{txtdec@thenextpage}

\newtoggle{txtdec@unfinisheddecor}
\newtoggle{txtdec@stayonpage}
\newtoggle{txtdec@stayondecor}
\newtoggle{txtdec@stayonline}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33765/105447
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}

% the drawing macros

\newcommand{\txtdec@draw@all}{%
  \draw[tdcolor, line width=\LineWidth, rounded corners=\CornerRadius] ($(\Xbegin,\Ybegin)+(-\BorderDispl,-\txtdec@depth)$) rectangle ($(\Xend,\Yend)+(\BorderDispl,\txtdec@height-\txtdec@depth)$) ;
}

\newcommand{\txtdec@draw@begin}{%
  \draw[tdcolor, line width=\LineWidth, rounded corners=\CornerRadius]
    ($(\Xlineend,\Ylineend)+(0,\txtdec@height-\txtdec@depth)$) --
    ($(\Xbegin,\Ybegin)+(-\BorderDispl,\txtdec@height-\txtdec@depth)$) --
    ($(\Xbegin,\Ybegin)+(-\BorderDispl,-\txtdec@depth)$) --
    ($(\Xlineend,\Ylineend)+(0,-\txtdec@depth)$) ;
}

\newcommand{\txtdec@draw@middle}{%
  \draw[tdcolor, line width=\LineWidth] ($(\Xlinebegin,\Ylinebegin)+(0,-\txtdec@depth)$) -- ($(\Xlineend,\Ylineend)+(0,-\txtdec@depth)$) ;
  \draw[tdcolor, line width=\LineWidth] ($(\Xlinebegin,\Ylinebegin)+(0,\txtdec@height-\txtdec@depth)$) -- ($(\Xlineend,\Ylineend)+(0,\txtdec@height-\txtdec@depth)$) ;
}

\newcommand{\txtdec@draw@end}{%
  \draw[tdcolor, line width=\LineWidth, rounded corners=\CornerRadius]
  ($(\Xlinebegin,\Ylinebegin)+(0,\txtdec@height-\txtdec@depth)$) --
  ($(\Xend,\Yend)+(\BorderDispl,\txtdec@height-\txtdec@depth)$) --
  ($(\Xend,\Yend)+(\BorderDispl,-\txtdec@depth)$) --
  ($(\Xlinebegin,\Ylinebegin)+(0,-\txtdec@depth)$)   ;
}

% using soul to set tikzmarks

\def\SOUL@tdleaders{%
  \stepcounter{txtdec@hyphmark}%
  \tikzmark{p\thepage.d\arabic{txtdec@decormark}.\arabic{txtdec@hyphmark}}%
  \leaders\hrule\@depth\z@\@height\z@\relax
}

\def\SOUL@tdunderline#1{{%
    \setbox\z@\hbox{#1}%
    \dimen@=\wd\z@
    \dimen@i=\SOUL@uloverlap
    \advance\dimen@2\dimen@i
    \rlap{%
      \null
      \kern-\dimen@i
      \SOUL@ulcolor{\SOUL@tdleaders\hskip\dimen@}%
      \hskip\dimen@
    }%
    \unhcopy\z@
  }}

\def\SOUL@tdpreamble{%
  \spaceskip\SOUL@spaceskip
  \stepcounter{txtdec@decormark}%
  \setcounter{txtdec@hyphmark}{0}%
  \tikzmark{p\thepage.d\arabic{txtdec@decormark}.begin}%
}
\def\SOUL@tdeverysyllable{%
  \SOUL@tdunderline{%
    \the\SOUL@syllable
    \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
  }%
  \stepcounter{txtdec@hyphmark}%
  \tikzmark{p\thepage.d\arabic{txtdec@decormark}.\arabic{txtdec@hyphmark}}%
}
\def\SOUL@tdeveryhyphen{%
  \discretionary{%
    \unkern
    \SOUL@tdunderline{%
      \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@hyphkern
      \SOUL@sethyphenchar
    }%
    \stepcounter{txtdec@hyphmark}%
    \tikzmark{p\thepage.d\arabic{txtdec@decormark}.\arabic{txtdec@hyphmark}}%
  }{}{}%
}
\def\SOUL@tdeveryexhyphen#1{%
  \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@hyphkern
  \SOUL@tdunderline{#1}%
  \stepcounter{txtdec@hyphmark}%
  \tikzmark{p\thepage.d\arabic{txtdec@decormark}.\arabic{txtdec@hyphmark}}%
  \discretionary{}{}{%
    \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
  }%
}
\def\SOUL@tdpostamble{%
  % create an extra mark, vertically displaced, to create an exit condition for the last line
  \stepcounter{txtdec@hyphmark}%
  \raisebox{-5pt}{\tikzmark{p\thepage.d\arabic{txtdec@decormark}.\arabic{txtdec@hyphmark}}}%
  \tikzmark{p\thepage.d\arabic{txtdec@decormark}.end}%
}
\def\SOUL@tdsetup{%
  \SOUL@setup
  \let\SOUL@preamble\SOUL@tdpreamble
  \let\SOUL@everysyllable\SOUL@tdeverysyllable
  \let\SOUL@everyhyphen\SOUL@tdeveryhyphen
  \let\SOUL@everyexhyphen\SOUL@tdeveryexhyphen
  \let\SOUL@postamble\SOUL@tdpostamble
}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\textdecor{\SOUL@tdsetup\SOUL@}

% get the drawing done AtBeginShipout

\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
    % getting the number of the next page
    \setcounter{txtdec@thenextpage}{\thepage}%
    \stepcounter{txtdec@thenextpage}%
    % if the current decoration occurs on this page, stay on it
    \iftikzmark{p\thepage.d\arabic{txtdec@decordraw}.\arabic{txtdec@hyphdraw}}{%
      \toggletrue{txtdec@stayonpage}}{}%
    \whileboolexpr{togl {txtdec@stayonpage}}{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \setlength{\txtdec@height}{\f@size pt}%
        \iftikzmark{p\thepage.d\arabic{txtdec@decordraw}.begin}{%
          % if current decor begins in current page, get coordinates
          \gettikzxy{(pic cs:p\thepage.d\arabic{txtdec@decordraw}.begin)}{\Xbegin}{\Ybegin}}{%
          % if current decor begins in previous page, set to top left of the page
          \gettikzxy{(current page.north west)}{\Xbegin}{\Ybegin}}%
        \iftikzmark{p\thepage.d\arabic{txtdec@decordraw}.end}{%
          % if current decor ends in current page, get coordinates
          \gettikzxy{(pic cs:p\thepage.d\arabic{txtdec@decordraw}.end)}{\Xend}{\Yend}}{%
          % if current decor ends in future page, set to bottom right of the page
          \gettikzxy{(current page.south east)}{\Xend}{\Yend}}%
        \ifdim\Ybegin=\Yend % the simplest case, a single line
          \txtdec@draw@all
          \stepcounter{txtdec@decordraw}%
        \else % current textdecor has a line break          
          \toggletrue{txtdec@stayondecor}%
          \whileboolexpr{togl {txtdec@stayondecor}}{%
            \gettikzxy{(pic cs:p\thepage.d\arabic{txtdec@decordraw}.\arabic{txtdec@hyphdraw})}{\Xlinebegin}{\Ylinebegin}%
            \edef\Xcurrent{\Xlinebegin}%
            \edef\Ycurrent{\Ylinebegin}%
            \edef\Xnext{\Xcurrent}%
            \edef\Ynext{\Ycurrent}%
            \toggletrue{txtdec@stayonline}%
            \whileboolexpr{togl {txtdec@stayonline}}{%
              \ifdim\Ycurrent=\Ynext
                \stepcounter{txtdec@hyphdraw}%
                % if the following tikzmark exists, we are at a page break
                \iftikzmark{p\arabic{txtdec@thenextpage}.d\arabic{txtdec@decordraw}.\arabic{txtdec@hyphdraw}}{%
                  \edef\Xcurrent{\Xnext}%
                  \edef\Ycurrent{\Ynext}%
                  \gettikzxy{(current page.south east)}{\Xnext}{\Ynext}
                  \togglefalse{txtdec@stayondecor}%
                }{% else, we remain on the same page
                  \iftikzmark{p\thepage.d\arabic{txtdec@decordraw}.\arabic{txtdec@hyphdraw}}{%
                    \edef\Xcurrent{\Xnext}%
                    \edef\Ycurrent{\Ynext}%
                    \gettikzxy{(pic cs:p\thepage.d\arabic{txtdec@decordraw}.\arabic{txtdec@hyphdraw})}{\Xnext}{\Ynext}}{}%
                }%
              \else
                \edef\Xlineend{\Xcurrent}%
                \edef\Ylineend{\Ycurrent}%
                % if we are on the first line of the current decoration
                \ifdim\Ylinebegin=\Ybegin
                  \txtdec@draw@begin
                \else
                  % if we are on the last line of the current decoration
                  \ifdim\Ycurrent=\Yend
                    \txtdec@draw@end
                    \stepcounter{txtdec@decordraw}%
                    \setcounter{txtdec@hyphdraw}{1}%
                    \togglefalse{txtdec@stayondecor}%
                  % if we are in a middle line of the decoration
                  \else
                    \txtdec@draw@middle
                  \fi
                \fi
                \togglefalse{txtdec@stayonline}%  
              \fi
            }%
          }%
        \fi
      \end{tikzpicture}%
      % if the beginning of the next decor does not exist in this page, leave this page
      \iftikzmark{p\thepage.d\arabic{txtdec@decordraw}.begin}{}{%
        \togglefalse{txtdec@stayonpage}}%
      % if the continuation of the current decor exists in the next page, leave this page
      \iftikzmark{p\arabic{txtdec@thenextpage}.d\arabic{txtdec@decordraw}.\arabic{txtdec@hyphdraw}}{%
        \togglefalse{txtdec@stayonpage}}{}% 
    }%
  }%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\vspace*{5cm}

Lorem ipsum \textdecor{dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing}
elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae,
felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget,
consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.  \textdecor{Donec vehicula augue
  eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristi-que senectus et netus
  et malesuada fames ac -- turpis --- egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras
  viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla
  ultrices.} Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida
placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac,
nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac,
nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget
risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis,
diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.  Nam dui ligula,
fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor
lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae,
ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum,
erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi.  Morbi ac
orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa.  Nam dui ligula,
fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor
lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae,
ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum,
erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi.  Morbi ac
orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa.  \textdecor{Nam
  dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel,
  wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at,
  lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed
  accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio
  metus a mi.  Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut
  massa.  Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin
  vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium
  at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed
  accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio
  metus a mi.  Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut
  massa.  Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla.} Cum sociis natoque
penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum
turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.

\begin{quotation}
  Lorem ipsum \textdecor{dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing}
  elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae,
  felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy
  eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.  \textdecor{Donec
    vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristi-que
    senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac -- turpis ---
    egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et
    lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices.} Phasellus eu tellus
  sit amet tortor gravida placerat.
\end{quotation}

\begin{itemize}
\item Lorem ipsum \textdecor{dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing}
  elit.
\item Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae,
  felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy
  eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. \textdecor{Donec vehicula
    augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristi-que senectus et
    netus et malesuada fames ac -- turpis --- egestas. Mauris ut leo.}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent solution!!! I kindly wonder if there is support for this in beamer as well as inline listings!?

Comment: @M.AlJumaily I don't know. I'd expect no problem with beamer, but probably no listings. Did you try it? Anyway, the limits of this are those of soul.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try it in but [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351374/167081) might help. This [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Bi85QWB3) has a minimal example. There isn't any errors occurring and the `fragile` doesn't have any effect. Lastly, why isn't there an auto line break in inline listings setting? I search everywhere and no one has a solution. Is it even possible in LaTeX2ε?

Comment: @M.AlJumaily Oh, so `beamer` also tampers with `\tikzmark`, it never ceases to surprise me at how much "a different world" it is. About listings, again, I don't know. If you're struggling with something specific, you should probably ask a question about it. But, in my experience, these decorations require quite some effort, so you'd need some luck to find someone willing.

Comment: It seems that [LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648457/make-hl-include-linebreaks#comment1616260_648457) is required for auto breaking. My request is to having autobreakle inline listing code. [TColorBox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494043/inline-declaretotaltcbox-using-tcolorbox) doesn't support this either.

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for a way to do this, based on the soul-tikz approach and could get somewhere based on the answer you linked to.

The original structure for this is Antal Spector-Zabusky's (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6029/105447), but I started from Gonzalo Medina's variation of it (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52336/105447).

There is much of the code that is beyond my reach, but I started from a simple idea and could adapt the relevant parts of it. The idea was to displace a little the vertical lines starting and ending the "box", so as to be able to add corners to it. The displacement itself is welcome, for it gets visually better if these vertical lines are not too close to the first/last character. But it is also a necessity (as far as I get it), for it seemed to me difficult to shorten the horizontal lines for the same purpose.

Regarding the importance of `soul` mentioned above in the comments, the point is, as far as I understand it, that `soul` is used to define the basic coordinates for the drawing, but the drawing itself is performed by TikZ. In other words, the drawing part of Antal Spector-Zabusky's idea is not based on `soul`'s `\hl` macro. True, along the way, coordinates are set for every hyphenation point, so it is indeed difficult to tamper with the top and bottom lines.

The result is the following:

[image]

Or closer:

[image]

The code used to produce it was:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\newlength\LineWidth
\setlength\LineWidth{0.7pt}

\newlength\CornerRadius
\setlength\CornerRadius{2pt}

\newlength\baseliney
\setlength\baseliney{-1.5pt}

\newlength\heighty
  \makeatletter
    \setlength{\heighty}{\f@size pt}
  \makeatother

\colorlet{HLcolor}{black}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\highlight@DoHighlight{%
    \draw[HLcolor,line width=\LineWidth,opacity=.3]  ($(begin highlight)+(0,\baseliney)$) -- ($(end highlight)+(0,\baseliney)$) ;
    \draw[HLcolor,line width=\LineWidth,opacity=.3]  ($(begin highlight)+(0,\baseliney+\heighty)$) -- ($(end highlight)+(0,\baseliney+\heighty)$) ;
}

\newcommand{\highlight@BeginHighlight}{
    \coordinate (begin highlight) at (0,0) ;
}

\newcommand{\highlight@EndHighlight}{
    \coordinate (end highlight) at (0,0) ;
}

\newdimen\highlight@previous
\newdimen\highlight@current

\DeclareRobustCommand*\circ[1][]{%
    \tikzset{this highlighter/.style={#1}}%
    \SOUL@setup
    %
    \def\SOUL@preamble{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \highlight@BeginHighlight
        \draw[HLcolor,line width=\LineWidth,opacity=.3]  ($(begin highlight)+(-\CornerRadius,\baseliney+\CornerRadius)$) -- ($(begin highlight)+(-\CornerRadius,\baseliney+\heighty-\CornerRadius)$) ;
        \draw[HLcolor,line width=\LineWidth,opacity=.3] ($(begin highlight)+(0,\baseliney+\heighty)$) arc [radius=\CornerRadius, start angle=90, end angle=180];
        \draw[HLcolor,line width=\LineWidth,opacity=.3] ($(begin highlight)+(0-\CornerRadius,\baseliney+\CornerRadius)$) arc [radius=\CornerRadius, start angle=180, end angle=270];
        \highlight@EndHighlight
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
    %
    \def\SOUL@postamble{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \highlight@EndHighlight
        \highlight@DoHighlight
        \draw[HLcolor,line width=\LineWidth,opacity=.3]  ($(end highlight)+(\CornerRadius,\baseliney+\CornerRadius)$) -- ($(end highlight)+(\CornerRadius,\baseliney+\heighty-\CornerRadius)$) ;
        \draw[HLcolor,line width=\LineWidth,opacity=.3] ($(end highlight)+(\CornerRadius,\baseliney+\heighty-\CornerRadius)$) arc [radius=\CornerRadius, start angle=0, end angle=90];
        \draw[HLcolor,line width=\LineWidth,opacity=.3] ($(end highlight)+(0,\baseliney)$) arc [radius=\CornerRadius, start angle=270, end angle=360];
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
    %
    \def\SOUL@everyhyphen{%
        \discretionary{%
            \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@hyphkern
            \SOUL@sethyphenchar
            \tikz[overlay, remember picture] \highlight@EndHighlight ;%
        }{%
    }{%
    \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
}%
}%
%
\def\SOUL@everyexhyphen##1{%
    \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@hyphkern
    \hbox{##1}%
    \discretionary{%
        \tikz[overlay, remember picture] \highlight@EndHighlight ;%
    }{%
}{%
\SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
}%
}%
%
\def\SOUL@everysyllable{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \path let \p0 = (begin highlight), \p1 = (0,0) in \pgfextra
    \global\highlight@previous=\y0
    \global\highlight@current =\y1
    \endpgfextra (0,0) ;
    \ifdim\highlight@current < \highlight@previous
    \highlight@DoHighlight
    \highlight@BeginHighlight
    \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \the\SOUL@syllable
    \tikz[overlay, remember picture] \highlight@EndHighlight ;%
}%
\SOUL@
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
    vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
    mauris. \circ{Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
        Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
        et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.} Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
    metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus
    eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
    quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
    faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur-
    abitur auctor semper nulla. \circ{Donec varius orci} eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue
    eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
    rutrum.

    Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi
    auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
    tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna,
    vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse
    ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. \circ{Cum sociis natoque penatibus et
        magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.} Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.

\end{document}
```

A limitation of this solution is that it limits the radius of the corners, for it also determines the displacement of the vertical lines and if you set the radius too large, the lines will invade surrounding words.

I've also let go everything related to filling, but I guess the same principle applied here could well be extended to include it.

I also adapted the code to be flexible to document font size and to have the main positioning settings globally defined at the beginning.

Comment: Neat :-) Some more.

Comment: @cfr, you might be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/427036/105447. Any thoughts there would be welcome.

Comment: @cfr, your wish is my command! ;)  (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429498/105447)

Comment: ?? What wish? Do you mean the 'Some more.' That wasn't a wish. It was just filler because SE wouldn't let me post my original comment because it was too short.

Comment: @cfr hahaha, yes I meant that wish! Well, as it turns out, that was not the worst misunderstanding that could happen. :)

Comment: Indeed, on the scale of misunderstandings, this one is happily very close to the almost-entirely-innocuous end. :-) I should have made more obvious filler!