# Box highlighting of text with rounded corners and hyphenation support

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, highlighting

I used [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en) to highlight text some text in paragraphs, it seems to work smoothly, but it disables text hyphenation, that the highlighted piece fo text cannot be start somwhere at one line and finish highlighting in the other. It is a problem.

The I tried [soul-tikz approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251182/box-highlighting-of-text-with-rounded-corners-soul-based). But the guys say that it is not pretty much extendable and that, for example, it is impossible to make rounded corners.

Thus, I am asking is there an approach to highlight text with a flexible box (that you can, for example, define rounded corners for it) but the text formatting is not affected by this highlighting (hyphenations, page breaks, ... work like there is no highlighting)?

Comment: Check http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6029/2388. It is easy to adapt the tikz-style in `\highlight@DoHighlight`.

Comment: It is not a full answer for your concerns, but perhaps you will be interested in a way to obtain rounded corners with the soul-tikz approach: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/363828/105447](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/363828/105447).