# How to trim a certain part of each character in a whole document?

Tags: programming

Got inspired from a nice article titled "[why All Caps is so hard to read](https://www.mity.com.au/blog/writing-readable-content-and-why-all-caps-is-so-hard-to-read)", I want to produce the following result for my document.

[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

## Question

How to do this automatically?

[image]

In order to be flexible, let  `r` be the ratio of `height` to remove (relative to the baseline).

Bonus: How to convert all characters to capital before trimming?

Comment: I think that, for it to be "automatic", you would actually need to create a truncated font.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes or you could "stack" a box over the text....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Don't think the thought hadn't crossed my mind `;^)`.

Comment: Sadly both `soul` and `ulem` don't work out of the box, as those apparently put the line behind the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course there is a minimal solution in ConTeXt.

```
\definebar
  [chop]
  [overstrike]
  [offset=.4,
   rulethickness=1.5,
   color=white]

\starttext

\chop{\WORDS{\input lorem }}

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity This is the complete input.  It's ConTeXt, not LaTeX.  You can compile online at http://live.contextgarden.net/

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{lipsum,color}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]


\vspace{-\dimexpr\parskip+\baselineskip}
\edef\NN{\the\prevgraf}
\noindent\begin{picture}(0,0)
\multiput(0,0)(0,12){12}{\textcolor{white}{\rule[-2pt]{\linewidth}{5pt}}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity if it was normal text you could use `\MakeUppercase` but `\lipsum` isn't expandable so doesn't work there.

Comment: your example used standalone so I rather assumed you only wanted single page but yes this just overprints lines going up from the end of the paragraph so if there is a page break mid paragraph it would need more work. You don't really want this for extended runs of multi-page text do you???

Comment: adding rules at a fixed distance to every page over the text is easy (just add a picture mode to the page foot that adds lines as here) if you want multi-page version with arbitrary text such as section headings etc and having to recalculate where the rules go for each text block it's possible but far too much work  for the answer here sorry. Hopefully  one  of the answers here will get you started so you can fill out to whatever full version you need. @ArtificialStupidity

Answer (score 2):

A Ti*k*Z solution (quickly modified version of a Ti*k*Z based multiline underline). It doesn't work across multiple pages and if the line distance is more than `\baselineskip`. This reuses ideas from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411361/117050 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411655/117050.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{refcount}

\tikzset{tikzCUT/.style={line width=1.1ex,white}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58590/121799
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \xdef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \xdef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\newlength\tikzCUT@length
\newcount\tikzCUT@count
\newcommand*{\tikzCUT}[1][0ex]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \tikzCUT@length=0ex\relax
  \else
    \tikzCUT@length=#1\relax
  \fi
  \tikzCUT@}
\newcounter{tikzCUTCounter}
\newcommand{\tikzCUT@}[2][-0.1ex]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay, baseline=(Begin.base)]{%
    \node[anchor=base,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,xshift=-\tikzCUT@length]
      (Begin) {\strut};
    \gettikzxy{($(Begin.base)-(current page.south west)$)}
      {\tikzCUT@bx}{\tikzCUT@by}%
  }%
  \stepcounter{tikzCUTCounter}%
  \tikzCUT@label{begin}%
  #2%
  \tikzCUT@label{end}%
  \expandafter\tikzCUT@pagecheck\expandafter{\the\c@tikzCUTCounter}%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay, baseline=(End.base)]{%
    \node[anchor=base,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,xshift=+\tikzCUT@length]
      (End) {\strut};%
    \gettikzxy{($(End.base)-(current page.south west)$)}
      {\tikzCUT@ex}{\tikzCUT@ey}%
  }%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \ifdim\dimexpr\tikzCUT@ey-\tikzCUT@by = 0pt
      % one line
      \draw[tikzCUT] ($(Begin.base)+(0,#1)$) -- ($(End.base)+(0,#1)$);%
    \else
      % multiple lines
      \draw
        ($(current page text area.west)-(\tikzCUT@length,0)$) node(WestLine){};
      \draw
        ($(current page text area.east)+(\tikzCUT@length,0)$) node(EastLine){};
      \tikzCUT@drawBtoE{#1}
      \ifdim\dimexpr\tikzCUT@by-\tikzCUT@ey>\baselineskip
        % more than two lines
        \bgroup
        \tikzCUT@drawMultipleLines{#1}{\baselineskip}
        \egroup
      \fi
    \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\newcommand*\tikzCUT@label[1]{%
  \null
  \@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
    \string\newlabel{tikzCUT:#1:\arabic{tikzCUTCounter}}
      {{\@currentlabel}{\arabic{page}}}}%
  \@esphack}
\newcommand*\tikzCUT@pagecheck[1]{%
  \typeout{\pageref{tikzCUT:begin:#1}}%
  \typeout{\pageref{tikzCUT:end:#1}}%
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{tikzCUT:begin:#1}=%
    \getpagerefnumber{tikzCUT:end:#1}\relax
  \else
    \GenericError{Multi-page warning}{AHHHH}{}%
  \fi}
\newcommand*\tikzCUT@drawMultipleLines[2]{%
  \tikzCUT@length=#2
  \tikzCUT@count=1
  \loop\ifdim\dimexpr\tikzCUT@by-\tikzCUT@count\tikzCUT@length>\tikzCUT@ey
  \draw[tikzCUT]
    ($(Begin.base -| WestLine)+(0,#1)-(0,\tikzCUT@count\tikzCUT@length)$)--
    ($(Begin.base -| EastLine)+(0,#1)-(0,\tikzCUT@count\tikzCUT@length)$);
  \advance\tikzCUT@count by 1
  \repeat}
\newcommand*\tikzCUT@drawBtoE[1]{%
  \draw[tikzCUT]
    ($(Begin.base)+(0,#1)$) -- ($(Begin.base -| EastLine)+(0,#1)$)
    ($(End.base)+(0,#1)$) -- ($(End.base -| WestLine)+(0,#1)$);}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tikzCUT{this foo away}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity it seems so, guess I pressed that button twice by accident :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another proposal based on Ti*k*Z and lineno. You only need to adjust `\TruncateRatio` to get a different truncation ratio `r`. If you want to truncate only a portion of your text, put it bewtween `\begin{runninglinenumbers}` and `\end{runninglinenumbers}` (and comment out `\linenumbers`). David Carlisle's comments on `\MakeUppercase` apply here, too. The reason why I post this (given the other excellent answers) is that it is trivial to play with opacity and, perhaps more importantly, also works with equations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{%
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};%
}%from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402462/tikz-equivalent-of-pstricks-commands-ncbar-and-rnode/402466#402466

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\TruncateRatio}{0.5}
\renewcommand\makeLineNumber
        {\tikznode{left}{\strut}\ \rlap{\hskip\textwidth\ \tikznode{right}{\strut}}
        \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\fill[white](left.south)rectangle($(right.south)!\TruncateRatio!(right.north)$);}}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\lipsum[1]
     \begin{linenomath*}
       \begin{eqnarray*}
         b_1 &=& a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 \\
         b_2 &=& a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2
       \end{eqnarray*}
     \end{linenomath*}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Much better than my 1min adaptation!

Comment: But you shouldn't use `eqnarray` anymore!

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks! But I just copied the equation literally from the `lineno` manual. Seems like the authors didn't want to blow up their manual by loading additional packages, and I have the same reservation here. Needless to say that my propsal also works with `align` , but of course for fractions it will just kill the denominator. In any case, there are also no instructions from the OP how to deal with equations, I guess that you will always find a pathological case with subscripts and so on.