# TikZ drawing across two lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

this is perhaps a bit of a weird request, but I was wondering if it's possible to have a TikZ drawing start on one line, stop at the page margin, and continue in the next line. I'm aware that you can create a linebreak with the align command and \, but that simply moves the text entered after \ directly below the text before \.

Basically what I'd like to accomplish is SQUARESQUARESQUARE (linebreak)
SQUARESQUARESQUARE.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...Can you elaborate your question with a screen shot or the coding what you tried so far? It is easy to help you in a better way...

Comment: Yes, this is possible: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411361/117050, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411655/117050