# Can tikz menu items (as defined by menukeys pkg) be made to go across multiple lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf, menukeys

I have a big problem regarding the `menukeys` package, which uses `tikz` to allow you to graphically represent menus/file paths. The major problem: no linebreaks. If a menu item happens to exceed the line length, instead of switching to a new line, it just keeps going endlessly (becoming unreadable).

So, my question is: How do I get the individual `tikz` drawings to adhere to line breaks?

For the record, I mean something like:

```
                  |---------||----------------------------||---------
Lorem ipsum dolor |sit amet || consectetur adipiscing elit|| sed do 
                  |---------||----------------------------||---------
-------------------------|
eiusmod tempor incididunt| ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
-------------------------|
```

I've already seen this wonderful post ([Boxed text, multiline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411339/boxed-text-multiline/411361#411361)), but since I'm a LaTeX novice, I'm struggling to understand how it works and how I can apply it to the menu design I have to use (not by choice XD).

I'd be super-grateful if the community could help me figure this out!

Here's the current menu style code I'm using (sorry for the bleep-outs, but I don't want to get in trouble for revealing the custom macro names):

```
\usepackage{menukeys}
\copymenustyle{********}{roundedmenus}
\newmenustylesimple{xxxxxxxx}{%
  tw@set@tikz@colors,
  rounded corners=0.3ex,
  inner sep=0pt,
  inner xsep=2pt,
  text height=1.825ex,
  text depth=0.7ex,
  minimum width=0.7ex,
  font=\relsize{-1}\xxxfontnamexxx,
  signal,
  signal to=nowhere,
  signal pointer angle=110,
}{gray}
\makeatletter
\tw@declare@style*{*******}{% create style manually due to signal to and signal from diffs
   \tikz[baseline={($(tw@node.base)+(0,-0.2ex)$)}]{%
         \node(tw@node)[tw@roundedmenus@base,font=\relsize{-1}\normalfont,signal to=east,fill=gray!25]%
               {\strut\CurrentMenuElement};}%
}[\hspace{-0.2em}\hspace{0em plus 0.1em minus 0.05em}]%
{%
   \tikz[baseline={($(tw@node.base)+(0,-0.2ex)$)}]{%
         \node(tw@node)[tw@roundedmenus@base,font=\relsize{-1}\normalfont,signal from=west,signal to=east,fill=gray!25]%
               {\strut\CurrentMenuElement};}%
}{% Last Item
   \tikz[baseline={($(tw@node.base)+(0,-0.2ex)$)}]{%
         \node(tw@node)[tw@roundedmenus@base,font=\relsize{-1}\normalfont\bfseries,color=white,signal from=west,fill=gray]%
               {\strut\CurrentMenuElement};}%
}{% Other Items
   \tikz[baseline={($(tw@node.base)+(0,-0.2ex)$)}]{%
         \node(tw@node)[tw@roundedmenus@base,font=\relsize{-1}\normalfont,color=white,fill=gray]{\strut\CurrentMenuElement};}%
}{gray}
\makeatother
\renewmenumacro{\menu}{********} % default: menus
\renewmenumacro{\directory}{xxxxxxx} % default: paths
\renewmenumacro{\keys}{xxxxxxxxxx} % default: roundedkeys
\renewmenumacro{\directory}[/]{paths}
```

((btw, apologies for the (somewhat) duplicate post. I couldn't expand on the original since I posted that before I signed up to the site. orz))

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, @BambOo, I can't do that. These are workplace documents, and the document structure that these fragments are used in is massive. This truly is the best I can do.

Comment: Do not be so humble, I am sure you can do better. You just have to put up a small example showing the issue. See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for some ideas on how to proceed.

Comment: @BambOo, I'm sorry, but I truly do not know how to demonstrate this issue beyond what I've described here, since, like I said, this code is just a small part of a massive thing. I've already stated that the individual menu items cause a page overrun, since they do not break when the line ends. Since it seems I cannot comply with your request, feel free to close this topic and/or my account. Thank you for trying.

Comment: There is no point in closing your account... it is not even for us to decide. However, it is just more difficult to help you with the issue without being able to test code. I just looked at the `menukeys` documentation, there are multiple `hyphenatepaths` options that may solve your issue since they allow linebreaks. Test them and see if this helps

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because The OP did not answer after answer proposal and deleted his account.

Answer (score 2):

**This is not yet an answer, but it is far too long as a comment**

Well I can't know for sure if this will help but it may serve as a starting point for discussion. After removing all unnecessary or incomplete code, here is a working example that breaks the paths.

Could you have a look at this and edit your question so that we may move forward. Otherwise this question will be closed because of its incomplete informations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\makeatletter
\tw@declare@style*{mystyle}{% create style manually due to signal to and signal from diffs
   \tikz[baseline={($(tw@node.base)+(0,-0.2ex)$)}]{%
         \node(tw@node)[tw@roundedmenus@base,font=\relsize{-1}\normalfont,signal to=east,fill=gray!25]%
               {\strut\CurrentMenuElement};}%
}[\hspace{-0.2em}\hspace{0em plus 0.1em minus 0.05em}]%
{%
   \tikz[baseline={($(tw@node.base)+(0,-0.2ex)$)}]{%
         \node(tw@node)[tw@roundedmenus@base,font=\relsize{-1}\normalfont,signal from=west,signal to=east,fill=gray!25]%
               {\strut\CurrentMenuElement};}%
}{% Last Item
   \tikz[baseline={($(tw@node.base)+(0,-0.2ex)$)}]{%
         \node(tw@node)[tw@roundedmenus@base,font=\relsize{-1}\normalfont\bfseries,color=white,signal from=west,fill=gray]%
               {\strut\CurrentMenuElement};}%
}{% Other Items
   \tikz[baseline={($(tw@node.base)+(0,-0.2ex)$)}]{%
         \node(tw@node)[tw@roundedmenus@base,font=\relsize{-1}\normalfont,color=white,fill=gray]{\strut\CurrentMenuElement};}%
}{gray}
\makeatother


\renewmenumacro{\directory}[/]{mystyle}

\begin{document}
\directory{Macintosh HD/Users/Your Name/Documents/Users/Your Name/Documents/Users/Your Name/Documents/Users/Your Name/Documents/Users/Your Name/Documents}
\end{document}
```

[image]