# How to line-break a framed text box?

Tags: line-breaking, framed

Is it possible to line-break a framed text box in LaTeX? If so, is it necessary to use some package to do so, and what is the name of that package?

**EDIT:** For greater clarity, let me give an example. Suppose I am typing a line of text and I put a long word in a framed box at the end of this line. Because by default LaTeX will not line-break such a framed box it will stick out of the right margin of text. My question concerns the possibility of line-breaking this framed text box over to the left side of the next line. In this way, both the text *and the frame itself* would be line-breaked from the right side of the given line to the left side of the next line.

Comment: No, you do not *need* a package, e.g. `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{3cm}
This is a rather long sentence with no meaning.
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}` works, but you may enjoy the nice options `tcolorbox` offers.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not being clear: I want the frame itself to break over a line.

Comment: Sorry, can you try to rephrase? Or are you looking for https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/411339 ?

Comment: I think that's what I'm looking for, although it looks awfully complicated :(

Comment: Can you post `MWE`? and also provide more clear picture on your requirement..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know only a trick, which works only manually:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{fbox}
\begin{document}

We look inside the alternate reality of the president’s 
Twitter account, where he absorbs and amplifies a 
noxious stream of disinformation.

We look inside the alternate reality of the \fbox[lbt]{presi-} \fbox[rbt]{dent’s} 
Twitter account, where he absorbs and amplifies a 
noxious stream of disinformation.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where can I find documentation on the optional [lbt] and [rbt] arguments to the \fbox command?

Comment: I suppose in the documentation of the package ... ;-)

Comment: Ah, didn't realize fbox was also a package since one can use the \fbox command without loading any packages. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to create a framed box is:

```
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{framed}
blah blah...
\end{framed}
```

This allows `line break`, `page break` etc.

Framed boxes with many custom styles then `tcolorbox` and `tikz` packages are preferable.

`mdframed` package also one of nice package which supports framed box with breaking option...