# Unicode character within tikz textbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, unicode

I use the following code from this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411361/165606) to box-up selected inline text.

```
% Multiline Textbox

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58590/121799
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \global\edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \global\edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\BoxMe}[2][0.5pt]{%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay, baseline=(Begin.base)]{%
\node[anchor=base,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (Begin) {\strut};}#2%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay, baseline=(End.base)]{%
\node[anchor=base,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (End) {\strut};}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\gettikzxy{($(Begin.north)-(current page.south west)$)}{\BeginxN}{\BeginyN}
\gettikzxy{($(End.north)-(current page.south west)$)}{\EndxN}{\EndyN}%\typeout{\BeginyN\space\EndyN}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mytest}{\EndyN-\BeginyN}
\ifnum\mytest=0\relax% begin and and in the same line %\typeout{begin and end in the same line}
\draw[thick,-] ($(Begin.north)-(#1,0)$) -- ($(Begin.south)-(#1,0)$)
-- ($(End.south)+(#1,0)$) -- ($(End.north)+(#1,0)$) -- cycle;
\else% \typeout{end below begin}
\path (current page text area.north west) -- (current page text area.south west)
node(WestLine)[left]{};
\path (current page text area.north east) -- (current page text area.south east)
node(EastLine)[right]{};
\gettikzxy{($(End.north)-(current page.south west)$)}{\EndxN}{\EndyN}
\gettikzxy{($(Begin.south)-(current page.south west)$)}{\BeginxS}{\BeginyS}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mytest}{\BeginyS-\EndyN+1pt}% \typeout{\mytest}
\ifnum\mytest<2\relax% \typeout{end in the next line after begin}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mytest}{\BeginxS-\EndxN}% \typeout{\mytest}
\ifnum\mytest>0\relax%
\draw[thick,-] (Begin.north -| EastLine) -- ($(Begin.north)-(#1,0)$) --
($(Begin.south)-(#1,0)$) -- (Begin.south -| EastLine);
\draw[thick,-] (End.south -| WestLine) -- ($(End.south)+(#1,0)$) --
($(End.north)+(#1,0)$) -- (End.north -| WestLine);
\else
\draw[thick,-] ($(Begin.north)-(#1,0)$) -- ($(Begin.south)-(#1,0)$) --
(Begin.south -| WestLine) -- (End.south -| WestLine)
-- ($(End.south)+(#1,0)$) -- ($(End.north)+(#1,0)$) -- (End.north -| EastLine)
-- (Begin.north -| EastLine) -- cycle;
\fi
\else
\draw[thick,-] ($(Begin.north)-(#1,0)$) -- ($(Begin.south)-(#1,0)$) --
(Begin.south -| WestLine) -- (End.south -| WestLine)
-- ($(End.south)+(#1,0)$) -- ($(End.north)+(#1,0)$) -- (End.north -| EastLine)
-- (Begin.north -| EastLine) -- cycle;
\fi
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

Unicode characters that have been boxed up do not display properly.

## Sample Document:

```
% Created 2021-03-24 Wed 03:05
% Intended LaTeX compiler: xelatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{ctexart}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{zhnumber} % package for Chinese formatting of date time (use /zhtoday)
\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime} % set date time to numeric

% For Generation of Citations and Bibliography
\usepackage[notes, isbn=false, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{/Users/satibodhi/Creation/notes/bibliography/thesis}

% Dummy Text for Testing

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{zhlipsum}

% Multiline Textbox

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58590/121799
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \global\edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \global\edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\BoxMe}[2][0.5pt]{%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay, baseline=(Begin.base)]{%
\node[anchor=base,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (Begin) {\strut};}#2%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay, baseline=(End.base)]{%
\node[anchor=base,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (End) {\strut};}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\gettikzxy{($(Begin.north)-(current page.south west)$)}{\BeginxN}{\BeginyN}
\gettikzxy{($(End.north)-(current page.south west)$)}{\EndxN}{\EndyN}%\typeout{\BeginyN\space\EndyN}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mytest}{\EndyN-\BeginyN}
\ifnum\mytest=0\relax% begin and and in the same line %\typeout{begin and end in the same line}
\draw[thick,-] ($(Begin.north)-(#1,0)$) -- ($(Begin.south)-(#1,0)$)
-- ($(End.south)+(#1,0)$) -- ($(End.north)+(#1,0)$) -- cycle;
\else% \typeout{end below begin}
\path (current page text area.north west) -- (current page text area.south west)
node(WestLine)[left]{};
\path (current page text area.north east) -- (current page text area.south east)
node(EastLine)[right]{};
\gettikzxy{($(End.north)-(current page.south west)$)}{\EndxN}{\EndyN}
\gettikzxy{($(Begin.south)-(current page.south west)$)}{\BeginxS}{\BeginyS}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mytest}{\BeginyS-\EndyN+1pt}% \typeout{\mytest}
\ifnum\mytest<2\relax% \typeout{end in the next line after begin}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mytest}{\BeginxS-\EndxN}% \typeout{\mytest}
\ifnum\mytest>0\relax%
\draw[thick,-] (Begin.north -| EastLine) -- ($(Begin.north)-(#1,0)$) --
($(Begin.south)-(#1,0)$) -- (Begin.south -| EastLine);
\draw[thick,-] (End.south -| WestLine) -- ($(End.south)+(#1,0)$) --
($(End.north)+(#1,0)$) -- (End.north -| WestLine);
\else
\draw[thick,-] ($(Begin.north)-(#1,0)$) -- ($(Begin.south)-(#1,0)$) --
(Begin.south -| WestLine) -- (End.south -| WestLine)
-- ($(End.south)+(#1,0)$) -- ($(End.north)+(#1,0)$) -- (End.north -| EastLine)
-- (Begin.north -| EastLine) -- cycle;
\fi
\else
\draw[thick,-] ($(Begin.north)-(#1,0)$) -- ($(Begin.south)-(#1,0)$) --
(Begin.south -| WestLine) -- (End.south -| WestLine)
-- ($(End.south)+(#1,0)$) -- ($(End.north)+(#1,0)$) -- (End.north -| EastLine)
-- (Begin.north -| EastLine) -- cycle;
\fi
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}}

% Set default indentation

\setlength\parindent{24pt}

% Set Paper Size, Page Layout (another variable is 'bindingoffset')
\usepackage[margin = 1.5in, paper = a4paper, inner = 2.5cm,
outer = 2.5cm, top = 3cm, bottom = 2.5cm]{geometry}

% Keep paragraph indentation while having a line break in between paragraphs.
\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
\usepackage{parskip}
\restoreparindent

% Indent first paragraph.
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fontspec} % packages for title and section-heading font setting.
\usepackage{newunicodechar} % custom fallback font for certain unicode characters.
\usepackage{tocloft} % adding the tocloft package for toc customization
\usepackage{titletoc} % custom toc indentation and label width.

% Set Header and Numbering Depth
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

% Set Font.
\setsansfont{Calibri}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman} % Set serifed font to Calibri. Originally set to 'Times New Roman', but it cannot display certain characters such as ①②③.
\setCJKmainfont{Songti TC}
\setCJKsansfont{Kaiti TC} % Set Chinese font. NOTE: Remember to append CJK before of the font class. CJK HAS to be there for the font to show.
\setCJKmonofont{PingFang TC}

% Set fallback fonts for ㊀ characters.

\newunicodechar{㊀}{{\ttfamily ㊀}}
\newunicodechar{㊁}{{\ttfamily ㊁}}
\newunicodechar{㊂}{{\ttfamily ㊂}}
\newunicodechar{㊃}{{\ttfamily ㊃}}
\newunicodechar{㊄}{{\ttfamily ㊄}}
\newunicodechar{㊅}{{\ttfamily ㊅}}
\newunicodechar{㊆}{{\ttfamily ㊆}}
\newunicodechar{㊇}{{\ttfamily ㊇}}
\newunicodechar{㊈}{{\ttfamily ㊈}}
\newunicodechar{㊉}{{\ttfamily ㊉}}
\newunicodechar{・}{{\ttfamily ・}}

\newCJKfontfamily\rarechar{HanaMinB}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}
\newunicodechar{}{{\rarechar }}

% Set fallback fonts for ① characters.

\newunicodechar{①}{{\sffamily ①}}
\newunicodechar{②}{{\sffamily ②}}
\newunicodechar{③}{{\sffamily ③}}
\newunicodechar{④}{{\sffamily ④}}
\newunicodechar{⑤}{{\sffamily ⑤}}
\newunicodechar{⑥}{{\sffamily ⑥}}
\newunicodechar{⑦}{{\sffamily ⑦}}
\newunicodechar{⑧}{{\sffamily ⑧}}
\newunicodechar{⑨}{{\sffamily ⑨}}
\newunicodechar{⑩}{{\sffamily ⑩}}
\newunicodechar{✔}{{\sffamily ✔}}
\newunicodechar{Ⓐ}{{\sffamily Ⓐ}}
\newunicodechar{Ⓑ}{{\sffamily Ⓑ}}
\newunicodechar{Ⓒ}{{\sffamily Ⓒ}}


% WHEN \documentclass is set to {article},
% zhnum[style={Traditional,Financial}] doesn't work with the section counter,
% so we define our own counter and increase it every time in \thesection.

\newcounter{mysec}[section]
\renewcommand\thesection{%
    \addtocounter{mysec}{1}%
    \zhnum[style={Traditional,Financial}]{mysec}、} % 大標題序號：壹、貳、參、…
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\zhnum{subsection}、} % added a 、小標題序號：一、二、三、…
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{（\zhnum{subsubsection}）} % added parentheses
% (full-width, don't know if that's what you want) 副標題序號：（一）（二）（三）
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\arabic{paragraph}} % arabic numbering for paragraph
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph{} % no subparagraph numbering

% we have to adjust the spacing in the toc because the section label is longer than usual
% ottedcontents will be used instead. (see below)
% \addtolength\cftsecnumwidth{1em}
% \addtolength\cftsubsecindent{1em}
% \addtolength\cftsubsubsecindent{1em}

% Use dottedcontents from the titletoc package to adjust TOC indentation and label width.
 \dottedcontents{section}[3em]{}{3.5em}{1pc} % larger label width (3.5em) to accommodate double digits.
 \dottedcontents{subsection}[5.5em]{}{2.5em}{1pc}
 \dottedcontents{subsubsection}[7.5em]{}{2.5em}{1pc}
 \dottedcontents{paragraph}[9.5em]{}{2.5em}{1pc}
 \dottedcontents{subparagraph}[11.5em]{}{2.5em}{1pc}

% Set formats for each heading level. 'sffamily' will point to the sans-serif font. In this case, 「楷體」.

% here we need to make sure the normal section counter is accessed
\titleformat{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily\filcenter}
    {\zhnum[style={Traditional,Financial}]{section}、}{.5em}{}

\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\Large\bfseries\sffamily} % Set formats for each heading level. 'sffamily' will point to the sans-serif font. In this case, 「楷體」.

% The `titlesec` package is used over here to make use of `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` as headings. Up to five levels of headings can be implemented this way.

% no extra version for numberless is necessary since no numbers are used anyways
% also you get newlines from omitting the [display] in \titleformat already
\titleformat{\paragraph}[block]
    {\Large\bfseries\sffamily}{\theparagraph}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[block]
    {\large\mdseries\sffamily}{\thesubparagraph}{0.5em}{}
% we need the following so that they don't indent (second argument, 0em);
% you'll have to adjust the spacing though since this is not display style anymore:
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0em}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{.75ex plus .1ex}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph}{0em}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{.75ex plus .1ex}

% Set title font.
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{\sffamily}

% Set quotation font.
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newCJKfontfamily\quotefont{Kaiti TC}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\quotefont\normalsize}

% Tweak default settings.
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2} % Set line width.
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\bfseries\Large 目\hspace{0.5cm} 錄\hfill} % Translate content page title to Chinese.
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill} % Center contents title.
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{摘要} % Translate abstract title to Chinese.
\renewcommand{\tablename}{表} % Translate table to Chinese.
\renewcommand{\figurename}{圖} % Translate figure to Chinese.

% For text-boxes

\usepackage{mdframed}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\begin{mdframed}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\end{mdframed}}

% For tables

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}

% [FIXME] ox-latex 的設計不良導致 hypersetup 必須在這裡插入
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true, %把紅框框移掉改用字體顏色不同來顯示連結
  linkcolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  citecolor=[rgb]{0,0.47,0.68},
  filecolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  urlcolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  pagebackref=true,
  linktoc=all,}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}

顏色\(\BoxMe{容貌溫}\)【一九〇】\(\BoxMe{變}\)也。以其中心與人\(\BoxMe{交，悅也。中心悅}\)焉，遷于兄弟，戚也。\(\BoxMe{戚而}\)信之，親\(\BoxMe{也。親而篤之，}\)【一九一】愛\footnote{「愛」字，帛書字從「旡」從「夂」從「心」。}也。愛父，其繼愛人，仁也。·　\\

\end{document}
```

## Errors:

```
Missing character: There is no 容 in font Times New Roman/OT:script=latn;languag
e=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no 貌 in font Times New Roman/OT:script=latn;languag
e=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no 溫 in font Times New Roman/OT:script=latn;languag
e=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no 變 in font Times New Roman/OT:script=latn;languag
e=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no 交 in font Times New Roman/OT:script=latn;languag
e=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ， in font Times New Roman/OT:script=latn;languag
e=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no 悅 in font Times New Roman/OT:script=latn;languag
e=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no 也 in font Times New Roman/OT:script=latn;languag
e=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no 。 in font Times New Roman/OT:script=latn;languag
e=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no 中 in font Times New Roman/OT:script=latn;languag
e=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no 心 in font Times New Roman/OT:script=latn;languag
e=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no 悅 in font Times New Roman/OT:script=latn;languag
e=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no 戚 in font Times New Roman/OT:script=latn;languag
e=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no 而 in font Times New Roman/OT:script=latn;languag
e=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no 也 in font Times New Roman/OT:script=latn;languag
e=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no 。 in font Times New Roman/OT:script=latn;languag
e=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no 親 in font Times New Roman/OT:script=latn;languag
e=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no 而 in font Times New Roman/OT:script=latn;languag
e=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no 篤 in font Times New Roman/OT:script=latn;languag
e=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no 之 in font Times New Roman/OT:script=latn;languag
e=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ， in font Times New Roman/OT:script=latn;languag
e=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
```

Comment: Apparently, the `\(` `\)` which is required syntax when drafting inline LaTeX code in org mode is causing the error.