Cutting fboxes when lines break
Is there a way that fbox, at the end of the line, just stops (there is blank instead of the right side of the box) and restarts automatically on the next line (with a blank instead of the left side of the box)?
MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\fbox{This is a text too long to be on a single line, unfortunately the text does not come to line and we cannot see it anymore}

\end{document}


I am willing to define a new command or a new environment.

Sorry, your question not clear to me (excuse), can you post a screenshot for your requirement for easy understanding?

I know a bit of tcolorbox and I've already taken a look at the documentation. However, I could not find something on boxes breaking with lines (maybe I don't know how to search).

Is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251182/box-highlighting-of-text-with-rounded-corners-soul-based/363828#363828 what you are looking for? Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411339/boxed-text-multiline ?

Yes, the first one does. Thank you so much.

Should I close the question or is that okay?

idk if this is exactly what you're after, but you could put the \fbox{} command around a \parbox{}{}command where you specify the width of the text before a linebreak occurs in the first parameter of \parbox{}{} and insert the text in the second one. Here's what it'd look like in practice with your example text:

Here's the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{This is a text too long to be on a single line, 
unfortunately the text does not come to line and we cannot see it 
anymore}}

\end{document}

This probably isn't the best solution, but it's quite easy and doesn't require any additional packages - I hope it helps:)
Edit 1: I forgot to mention that the geometry package isn't necessary in case you were wondering. I just have a habit of using it for better formatting

Thank you. This is not what I was looking for but still I think it's interesting.
