# todonotes package: mark a block with the comment

Tags: todonotes

I like to know it it is possible to use todonotes for something like this:

```
text text
text text---
text text   |
text text   |-[comment box]
text text   |
text text---
text text
```

I want a comment box pointing to a start line and an end line (possible both are on different pages).
Thank you for help, I'm looking forward to your answers.

best regards,
Oli

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think you may also want to have a look to the first answer of [Highlighting arbitrary chunks of text connected to quotes in margins - Can this be done in TeX/LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49832/13304) although it is a solution that does not exploit todonotes.

Comment: Thank you for you idea - It is nice for small snippets.  But if you want to point to something distributed over three pages then it looks a bit ugly to highlight everything.

Comment: Then you may want to use other tools. When there is such amount of text to be put in evidence, I think the best solutions are provided by packages tcolorbox and mdframed as they support page breaks.