# Text not wrapping to margins if highlighted with \colorbox

Tags: margins, tcolorbox, highlighting, wrap, bullets

In a test file such as;

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Short line of text
    \item Comparatively long line of text to illustrate that latex is wrapping my text to a preset margin when I have not highlighted it.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

the text wraps with the preset margin definition. No problem.

However, if the text in either the bullet or subsequent sub-bullet lines are highlighted with `\colorbox{colour}{text}` then wrapping does not occur. I am using;

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
```

to modify text colours and my custom margin definitions are made by;

```
\usepackage[margin=1in,includefoot,includehead]{geometry}
```

Here is an example of the highlighting I wish to perform.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

\usepackage[margin=1in,includefoot,includehead]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Short line of text
    \item \colorbox{yellow}{Comparatively long line of text to illustrate that latex is not wrapping my text to a preset margin when it is being highlighted.}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \colorbox{yellow}{The problem persists with sub-bullet points too. I assume this is an issue with the coloring command and not my margin definitions.}
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

This is what the issue looks like, if I have not explained myself appropriately;

[image: Text not wrapping when highlighted]

Please note that if I continue writing in the same line after the highlighted section, the text will wrap as expected.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49832/highlighting-arbitrary-chunks-of-text-connected-to-quotes-in-margins-can-this?rq=1

Comment: there is package soul http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/soul/soul.pdf and framed http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/framed/framed.pdf

Answer (score 7):

`\colorbox` can't wrap around text, unless an additional `\parbox` inside of `\colorbox` is used. I've provided a command for this applying `\parbox` and reducing the available space by two `\fboxsep` spaces, otherwise it will overflow again into the margin.

I suggest to use `tcolorbox` rather (not easier to use, but more versatile)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{enhanced jigsaw, sharp corners,box align=center,boxrule=0pt}

% A special box for this
\newtcolorbox{highlightbox}[1][]{colback=yellow,enhanced jigsaw, sharp corners,box align=center,boxrule=0pt,boxsep=0pt,#1}

\usepackage[margin=1in,includefoot,includehead]{geometry}

\newcommand{\wrapcolorbox}[2][]{%
  \colorbox{#1}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{#2}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Short line of text
    \item \wrapcolorbox[green]{Comparatively long line of text to illustrate that latex is not wrapping my text to a preset margin when it is being highlighted.}
    \item \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow]
        Comparatively long line of text to illustrate that latex is not wrapping my text to a preset margin when it is being highlighted.
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item \begin{highlightbox}
            The problem persists with sub-bullet points too. I assume this is an issue with the coloring command and not my margin definitions.
          \end{highlightbox}
       \item \wrapcolorbox[green]{Comparatively long line of text to illustrate that latex is not wrapping my text to a preset margin when it is being highlighted.}
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this has been most helpful! The only issue I am now running into is continuing in plain text on the same line as highlighted text. I appreciate that the text we're customising is not being 'highlighted' in the conventional sense, but rather a box is being drawn around the lines on which our chosen text is.

Answer (score 1):

```
\item {\color{yellow}Comparatively long line of text to illustrate that latex is not wrapping my text to a preset margin when it is being highlighted.}
```

should wrap at the margin.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `\soul` package as described in [here](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/latex/highlight-text-in-latex-document)

Comment: It is much better if you provide an example of how to use the package in this specific context instead of only adding an link to an external website. Highlighting with the [`soul`](https://ctan.org/pkg/soul) package only works with "Postscript aware output drivers" according to the manual (section 2, footnote 5).