# How to highlight arabic texts with allowing line breaks?

Tags: line-breaking, highlighting, arabic

I would like to highlight some texts. For Latin texts the `\hl` command of the *soul* package works well, but not for Arabic texts.

(`\hl{SOME ARABIC TEXT}` has only a small *line* as output in the pdf file.)

I could use `\colorbox{yellow}{ARABIC TEXT}` but it doesn't allow line breaks.

(The command `\uline` of the *ulem* package works for Arabic text too, so maybe it is not so difficult to get an "Arabic" `\hl`?)

(Perhaps [the code of Leo Liu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48549/22969) could be helpful: It makes some yellow boxes which *cover* the Arabic texts.)

I'm using xelatex (TeX Live 2012). Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{ulem,soul}
%\usepackage{fontspec,color,xcolor,hyperref,xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguages{german}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

\begin{german}
Highlighting works for \hl{latin texts}.
\end{german}

\hl{عربي} % you will just see a vertical small yellow line

\end{document}
```

---

EDIT: With this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage{fontspec,color,xcolor,hyperref,xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguages{german}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Times New Roman}
\newcommand\hl{\bgroup\markoverwith % 
  {\textcolor{yellow}{\rule[-.5ex]{2pt}{2.5ex}}}\ULon}


\begin{document}
\begin{german}
Test \hl{for highlighting} text. %correct
\end{german}
\hl{عربي} % correct

\hl{عربي} % result: yellow box covers the word
\end{document}
```

I get the result:

[image: arabicTest]

So, in the first line the highlighting of the arabic text is correct - does someone know how to modify the code to make the hightlighting correct in the second line too?

Comment: It is very unlikely that you can do this due to `\special` bug/problems of TeX--XeT in RTL mode.

Comment: I thought it is possible to get a highlighting function that works with arabic texts as the the underline function `\uline` of `ulem`. (BTW: Thanks for xecolour.)

Comment: @VafaKhalighi Could you make that comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments:

> It is very unlikely that you can do this due to `\special` bug/problems of TeX--XeT in RTL mode.

The way that specials are handled by the TeX--XeT model (currently) used by XeTeX means this can't really be done.