# highlight text background

Tags: tcolorbox, shading

For a certain part of text, I needed to make the text bold + underlined in addition to changing the background color

I needed to do all this while maintaining hyphenation

Thus I could not use the underline command, I used Uline and also Ic ould not use the color box command, I had to use the tcolorbox.

I have only one issue which is that the Background text color does not stop where the text stops, it extends till the end of the line. IS there any Fix for This

HERE IS THE LINK FOR SIMPLIFIED ARABIC FONT, INSTALL IT ON YOUR SYSTEM TO RUN THE CODE: https://fontzone.net/font-details/simplified-arabic

I Am using polyglossia + xelatex
Here is the code with various examples:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage

[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage{fontspec} 

\usepackage{tcolorbox} 

\usepackage{ulem}

\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor = blue,anchorcolor = blue,citecolor = blue,filecolor = blue,urlcolor = blue]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{url,graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows,positioning,matrix,quotes, shapes.geometric,calc}  
\usepackage{rotating}  
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,locale=default,numerals=mashriq]{arabic} 
\setotherlanguages{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Simplified Arabic} 

\begin{document}

\chapter{}

\begin{bfseries}

\begin{tcolorbox}

[colframe=white,colback=lightgray]

\uline{

لتسهيل عملية الدراسة، من المحبب ان يبدأ الطالب بالدراسة من خلال ملحق رقم (2) لإحتوائه على أهم القواعد اللغوية المطلوبة لإتقان المواضيع الموضحة بفصول الكتاب المختلفة وذلك تسهيلاً على الطالب حتى يتجنب كثرة التفاصيل.}

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{bfseries}

\bigskip

\underline{\textbf{\colorbox{lightgray}{

لتسهيل عملية الدراسة، من المحبب ان يبدأ الطالب بالدراسة من خلال ملحق رقم (2) لإحتوائه على أهم القواعد اللغوية المطلوبة لإتقان المواضيع الموضحة بفصول الكتاب المختلفة وذلك تسهيلاً على الطالب حتى يتجنب كثرة التفاصيل.}}}

\bigskip

\uline{\textbf{\colorbox{lightgray}{

لتسهيل عملية الدراسة، من المحبب ان يبدأ الطالب بالدراسة من خلال ملحق رقم (2) لإحتوائه على أهم القواعد اللغوية المطلوبة لإتقان المواضيع الموضحة بفصول الكتاب المختلفة وذلك تسهيلاً على الطالب حتى يتجنب كثرة التفاصيل.}}}

\begin{bfseries}

\begin{tcolorbox}

[colframe=white,colback=lightgray]

\underline{
لتسهيل عملية الدراسة، من المحبب ان يبدأ الطالب بالدراسة من خلال ملحق رقم (2) لإحتوائه على أهم القواعد اللغوية المطلوبة لإتقان المواضيع الموضحة بفصول الكتاب المختلفة وذلك تسهيلاً على الطالب حتى يتجنب كثرة التفاصيل.}

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{bfseries}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note that `bfseries` is not an  environment but a switch: (`\bfseries`)

Comment: Maybe with  `\hl` command from `soul` (or rather `soulutf8`)?

Comment: Soul package changes font color, want to change Background color

Comment: May be these questions and answers can help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86152/1952, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5959/1952, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297736/1952

Comment: And [Visually highlighting symbolic material](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88973/13304) can also help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't make it work with the `soul` package. But your idea of using a `tcolorbox` might be an option.

I've stayed with `lualatex` and `babel` as with my answers to your other questions.

The white after the text is basically faked by drawing leaders with a white `\vrule` at the end of the text. You get some artefacts on screen, but I think it will print OK.

There are a lot of hacks in this though…

## MWE

Compile with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r,layout=counters]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}
\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}

\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{hl}[1][]{%
  frame empty, sharp corners, top=0pt, right=0pt, bottom=0pt, left=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt, toprule=0pt, rightrule=0pt, bottomrule=0pt, leftrule=0pt,
  colback=lightgray, fontupper=\bfseries,
  before upper=\selectlanguage{arabic}%
    {\color{white}\vrule width 1.5em},
  after upper={{\color{white}\leaders\vrule\hfill\null}},
  before=\noindent\begingroup\selectlanguage{english},after=\endgroup,
#1}

\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
لتسهيل عملية الدراسة، من المحبب ان يبدأ الطالب بالدراسة من خلال ملحق رقم (2)
لإحتوائه على أهم القواعد اللغوية المطلوبة لإتقان المواضيع الموضحة بفصول الكتاب
المختلفة وذلك تسهيلاً على الطالب حتى يتجنب كثرة التفاصيل.

\begin{hl}
  \uline{لتسهيل عملية الدراسة، من المحبب ان يبدأ الطالب بالدراسة من خلال ملحق
  رقم (2) لإحتوائه على أهم القواعد اللغوية المطلوبة لإتقان المواضيع الموضحة
  بفصول الكتاب المختلفة وذلك تسهيلاً على الطالب حتى يتجنب كثرة التفاصيل.}
\end{hl}

لتسهيل عملية الدراسة، من المحبب ان يبدأ الطالب بالدراسة من خلال ملحق رقم (2)
لإحتوائه على أهم القواعد اللغوية المطلوبة لإتقان المواضيع الموضحة بفصول الكتاب
المختلفة وذلك تسهيلاً على الطالب حتى يتجنب كثرة التفاصيل.

\begin{hl}[colback=yellow]
  \uline{لتسهيل عملية الدراسة، من المحبب ان يبدأ الطالب بالدراسة من خلال ملحق
  رقم (2) لإحتوائه على أهم القواعد اللغوية المطلوبة لإتقان المواضيع الموضحة
  بفصول الكتاب المختلفة وذلك تسهيلاً على الطالب حتى يتجنب كثرة التفاصيل.}
\end{hl}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Is there a way to make the highlight color a function in the command so that I may not need to redefine a new command for each HL color?

Comment: @Silva, yes, this is straight forward. See my updated answer.

Comment: when using this command, I got an issue to center the text: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/543079/begincenter-and-endcenter-is-not-working