# Highlighting text with ulem package

Tags: highlighting, ulem

Consider the following minimal example (taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48549/22969)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{ulem}
\newcommand\hl{\bgroup\markoverwith
  {\textcolor{yellow}{\rule[-.5ex]{2pt}{2.5ex}}}\ULon}
\begin{document}
This is a test \hl{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.} text.
\end{document}
```

If you look at the output carefully, you will notice that color has covered small parts of some leters. How is this fixed?

Here is a screenshot of the output:

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. I think a snapshot will help.

Comment: @LeoLiu: I have now added the screenshot. Look at the letters in the red rectangles.

Comment: OK, I know the problem. The yellow rule box after letter `f` is typeset after `f` but it covers the serif of `f`. I have no idea how to solve the problem properly.

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution is to use a `\rule` with smaller width; for instance

```
\newcommand\hl{\bgroup\markoverwith
  {\textcolor{yellow}{\rule[-.5ex]{1pt}{2.5ex}}}\ULon}
```

However there are still colors covering the letter f.

Following EDIT by Steven Segletes:

Since the answerer has not logged in for a while, I will edit the answer further.  The answer is on the right track, but must be reduced even further in width, to let's say `0.1pt`.  Here is the result, which overcomes the problem letters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{ulem}
\newcommand\hl{\bgroup\markoverwith
  {\textcolor{yellow}{\rule[-.5ex]{.1pt}{2.5ex}}}\ULon}
\begin{document}
This is a test \hl{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.} text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, there still may remain a slight problem with the `f`, which sticks out to the right of its bounding box:

[image]