# Glossaries and soul causing problems when used together, specifically \glsdisp

Tags: glossaries, soul

Unfortunately, the package `soul` does not coexist well with `glossaries`. From [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560975/alternative-to-the-soul-package) it seems that to get both packages to work within the same document one must make use of the `\soulregister` command.

This seems to be a viable workaround for `\gls`, as the following example demonstrates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{soul}

\soulregister \gls7
\newglossaryentry{test}{
  name=test,
  description=test
  }

\begin{document}
  \ul{\gls{test}}
  \clearpage
  \printglossary
\end{document}
```

If, by the same token, I try to add `\glsdisp` to the `\soulregister`, my .tex file does not compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{soul}
\soulregister \glsdisp7
\newglossaryentry{test}{
  name=test,
  description=test
  }

\begin{document}
  \ul{\glsdisp{test}{testing}}
  \clearpage
  \printglossary
\end{document}
```

If I compile the above, I get the following error for line 11:

> Missing number, treated as zero.

How do I get `glsdisp` to behave with `soul`?

Comment: I don't think you can. soulregister handles commands with one argument. Use lualatex + lua-ul instead.

Comment: does lua-ul provide highlighting functionality? That's actually what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Why don't you look into the documentation?