# making soulutf8 work with \(...\)

Tags: math-mode, soul

Is there any easy way to adapt `soulutf8` to work with LaTeX math mode delimiters?

As of now, compiling

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,soulutf8}
\begin{document}
Well, \hl{\(e^{i\pi}=-1\)}.
\end{document}
```

with `pdflatex` results in

```
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\SOUL@doword ...hskip \z@ \relax \the \SOUL@word }
                                                  \let \SOUL@errmsg \SOUL@er...
l.4 Well, \hl{\(e^{i\pi}=-1\)}
                              .
? X
```

Let us not go into [the discussion on which one is better: `$...$` or `\(...\)`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode); take it for granted that the typesetter has his/her reasons to prefer the second pair of delimiters.

P.S. As Heiko pointed out, the same problem exists in soul (which unfortunately seems to lack an active maintainer as of now), whose documentation specifically mentions this limitation.

Comment: @VasiliPupkin you can patch `soul` but only under the conditions of the LPPL (which clearly allows you to modify the package locally -- redistribution only under certain conditions)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Oh, I see now. There are two copyrights: one for the dtx file and another one for the sty file. Since there is no need to ship the sty file, its copyright can be effectively ignored.

Answer (score 4):

One could parse the argument of `\hl` to replace all `\(...\)` by `$...$` in that argument and then use the original definition of `\hl`. I'm not entirely sure whether the following is completely stable, though it worked for everything I've thrown at it so far.

*Edit:* minimise code by removing case which is never matched (`##3` is dot and `##2` is not) and not include the `\(.\)` tokens in every recursion of the replacement but only once (which suffices as those are in `##3` in the case of a recursion).

Note that there are cases of valid but strange syntax (if used outside of the argument of `\hl`) which fail here: If one mixes `$` and one of `\(` or `\)` as the delimiters the provided code fails; though `$a^b\)` or `\(a^b$` would be valid syntax `\hl{$a^b\)}` and `\hl{\(a^b$}` would fail as they don't match the required argument pattern of `\hl@grab`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,soulutf8}
\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\hlBAK\hl
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`.=4% changing catcode so the dot is never matched by ordinary text
\def\zz%
  {\endgroup
    \renewcommand\hl[1]
      {%
        \hl@grab##1\(.\)\endhl@grab
      }%
    \long\def\hl@grab##1\(##2\)##3\endhl@grab%
      {%
        \hl@grab@ifdot{##2}
          {\hlBAK{##1}}
          {\hl@grab##1$##2$##3\endhl@grab}%
      }%
    \long\def\hl@grab@ifdot##1%
      {%
        \ifx.##1%
          \expandafter\@firstoftwo
        \else
          \expandafter\@secondoftwo
        \fi
      }%
  }%
\zz
\begin{document}
Well, \hl{\(.e^{i\pi}=-1\) text \(2=2\).}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** The following provides a replacement using two macros, one to replace `\(` and one to replace `\)`. As a result the strange (but technically correct) syntax of `\(a^b$` and `$a^b\)` should also work as an argument to `\hl` (though this way `\hl{\(a^b\( text $a^b$}` would work, too, which is obviously not correct syntax).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,soulutf8}
\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\hlBAK\hl
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`.=4% changing catcode so the dot is never matched by ordinary text
\def\zz%
  {\endgroup
    \renewcommand\hl[1]
      {%
        \hl@grab@A##1\(.\endhl@grab
      }%
    \long\def\hl@grab##1\(##2\)##3\endhl@grab%
      {%
        \hl@grab@ifdot{##2}
          {\hlBAK{##1}}
          {\hl@grab##1$##2$##3\endhl@grab}%
      }%
    \long\def\hl@grab@A##1\(##2\endhl@grab%\)
      {%
        \hl@grab@ifdot{##2}
          {\hl@grab@B##1\).\endhl@grab}
          {\hl@grab@A##1$##2\endhl@grab}%
      }%
    \long\def\hl@grab@B##1\)##2\endhl@grab%
      {%
        \hl@grab@ifdot{##2}
          {\hlBAK{##1}}
          {\hl@grab@B##1$##2\endhl@grab}%
      }%
    \long\def\hl@grab@ifdot##1%
      {%
        \ifx.##1%
          \expandafter\@firstoftwo
        \else
          \expandafter\@secondoftwo
        \fi
      }%
  }%
\zz
\begin{document}
Well, \hl{\(.e^{i\pi}=-1\) text \(2=2\).}

\hl{$a^b\)}\hl{\(a^b$}

\hl{\(a \(b$ $}
\end{document}
```

---

Using `etl` as a faster, yet less versatile alternative to `l3regex` to also replace `\(` and `\)` inside of braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,soul}
\usepackage{etl}
\NewCommandCopy\hlBAK\hl
\ExplSyntaxOn
\renewcommand\hl[1]
  {
    \exp_args:Ne \hlBAK
      {
        \etl_token_replace_all_deep:eNn
          { \etl_token_replace_all_deep:nNn {#1} \( { $ } }
          \) { $ }
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \etl_token_replace_all_deep:nNn { e }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\hl{\emph{Some important \( m = ath \)}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @user49915 the changes made by `\makeatletter` and `\catcode\`.=4` are local to a group which is started by `\bgroup` and ended by `\zz` as the definition of `\zz` starts with an `\egroup`. This is a neat trick to not alter any catcodes while still defining stuff with non standard catcodes. Per convention those should be `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`, though, so you're right, the code is not perfect, I'll edit it.

Comment: @user49915 `\bgroup` is essentially the same as `{` (except that it doesn't have to be balanced while you define stuff), as a result `\bgroup` and `\egroup` can be balanced with `{` and `}`, while `\begingroup` must be balanced by `\endgroup`. It is convention (at least in l3) that you don't use `\bgroup` and `\egroup` for programming, so by that convention I should've used `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`. To see that `\makeatletter` has no effect anymore, you could place `\@gobble{this}` after `\zz`, it'll result in `You can't use \`\spacefactor' in vertical mode.`

Comment: I've just tested your code and got an error when trying `\hl{\emph{\(…\)}}`: running `latex` on https://pastebin.com/w5eDPm1J results in the error `! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\SOUL@dosyllable ...x {\SOUL@tt \the \SOUL@token }
                                                  \advance \SOUL@syllwidth \...` to the console. Might I ask you to take a look?

Comment: @AlMa0 problem is that the `\(` and `\)` tokens are hidden inside the argument to `\emph` where this code doesn't see them. Either use `$` directly or the `l3regex` variant provided by egreg (`l3regex` might be slower, but it will also find the tokens nested in groups).

Comment: @AlMa0 now there is also another alternative that uses `etl` instead of `l3regex` (this should be a bit faster than the regular expression based approach, though `etl` is less versatile than `l3regex`).

Comment: Works like a charm, thx! +1

Answer (score 4):

With the `l3regex` module it's quite easy and works for all `soul` commands. The idea is to redefine `\SOUL@start`, which is the macro that does all the business according to settings already made by the called macros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor,soulutf8}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \__l_SOUL_argument_tl
\cs_set_eq:Nc \SOUL_start:n { SOUL@start }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \SOUL_start:n { V }
\cs_set_protected:cpn {SOUL@start} #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \__l_SOUL_argument_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { \c{\(} (.*?) \c{\)} } % look for \(...\) (lazily)
   { \cM\$ \1 \cM\$ }      % replace with $...$
   \__l_SOUL_argument_tl
  \SOUL_start:V \__l_SOUL_argument_tl % do the usual
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Well, \hl{\(e^{i\pi}=-1\) text \(2=2\).}

Well, \ul{\(e^{i\pi}=-1\) text \(2=2\).}

Well, \so{\(e^{i\pi}=-1\) text \(2=2\).}

Well, \caps{\(e^{i\pi}=-1\) text \(2=2\).}

Well, \st{\(e^{i\pi}=-1\) text \(2=2\).}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you use `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` instead of `\exp_args:NV`?

Comment: @Skillmon Better compliance to the guidelines.

Comment: Simply amazing…

Answer (score 3):

The use of `\(` and `\)` is not supported by package `soul`, from the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/soul/soul.pdf):

> **§ 3 Mathematics:**
>
> Example: `\so{foo$x^3$bar}`
>
> Mathematic formulas are allowed, as long as they are surrounded by `$`.
>
> Note that the LaTeX equivalent `\(`...`\)` does not work.

Thus, the workaround with `$` remains:

```
\hl{$e^{i\pi}=-1$}
```

Comment: Given that you've worked on integrating soulutf8 into soul recently, would it be possible for us to ask you to integrate also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48502 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426036 (or equivalent means of solving the issues addressed by these answers) into soul.sty (unless this has already happened and is to appear soon in TeX Live, of course)?

Comment: @AlMa0 The integration work is done by David Carlisle and Ulrike Fischer AFAIK, I do not know the details. There is an [issue tracker](https://github.com/ho-tex/soul/issues) for bug reports and feature requests.

Comment: Already asked: https://github.com/ho-tex/soul/issues/6 .