# pdflatex + soulutf8 + German shorthands = eaten up ASCII chars

Tags: pdftex, babel, german, shorthands, soulutf

Feeding

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
%%% See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426036
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\hlBAK\hl
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`.=4% changing catcode so the dot is never matched by ordinary text
\def\zz%
  {\endgroup
    \renewcommand\hl[1]
      {%
        \hl@grab@A##1\(.\endhl@grab
      }%
    \long\def\hl@grab##1\(##2\)##3\endhl@grab%
      {%
        \hl@grab@ifdot{##2}
          {\hlBAK{##1}}
          {\hl@grab##1$##2$##3\endhl@grab}%
      }%
    \long\def\hl@grab@A##1\(##2\endhl@grab%\)
      {%
        \hl@grab@ifdot{##2}
          {\hl@grab@B##1\).\endhl@grab}
          {\hl@grab@A##1$##2\endhl@grab}%
      }%
    \long\def\hl@grab@B##1\)##2\endhl@grab%
      {%
        \hl@grab@ifdot{##2}
          {\hlBAK{##1}}
          {\hl@grab@B##1$##2\endhl@grab}%
      }%
    \long\def\hl@grab@ifdot##1%
      {%
        \ifx.##1%
          \expandafter\@firstoftwo
        \else
          \expandafter\@secondoftwo
        \fi
      }%
  }%
\zz

%%% See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48502
\makeatletter
\newdimen\SOUL@dimen %new
\def\SOUL@ulunderline#1{{%
    \setbox\z@\hbox{#1}%
    \SOUL@dimen=\wd\z@ %new
    \dimen@i=\SOUL@uloverlap
    \advance\SOUL@dimen2\dimen@i %\dimen@ exchanged too
    \rlap{%
        \null
        \kern-\dimen@i
        \SOUL@ulcolor{\SOUL@ulleaders\hskip\SOUL@dimen}% new
    }%
    \unhcopy\z@
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}\noindent
(Daten"~)""Ströme\\
\hl{(Daten"~)""Ströme}
\end{document}
```

to `pdflatex` results in the last character disappearing:

[image: two lines, the second is wrong]

Any idea on how to improve the preamble so that all the text within the background-highlighting command `\hl` appears even if the German shorthands are present?  In this question, we stick to `pdflatex` (no other engine).  (Yes, I am aware of the workaround `\hl{(Daten"~)}""\hl{Ströme}`.)

Comment: imho this is part of the "some things don't work" in soul. So don't use `""` or switch to lualatex and use lua-ul.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. As for `lualatex`, I plan a separate question (other things do not work there). Let's discuss only `pdflatex`-related issues here.

Comment: I don't see an easy way, if you really need Babel's shorthands. (Disabling them works fine.) There's another issue, which may or may not matter to you: Your text is typeset as `Str¨ome`, i.e. with a combining diaeresis instead of a proper ö, which makes searching your text much harder. 

PS: A very heavy-handed solution would be to add a sacrificial character in these cases, perhaps an `!`or similar. (Whitespace won't work.)

Comment: @Ingmar Thanks. I don't necessarily need the `\penalty`-related special functionality of shorthands within `\hl` (as it's for commenting a draft version of a document), but I do need the hyphens they may produce. As for `Str¨ome`, copying from the viewer `evince` and pasting into a text editor gives me a proper `ö`, and searching for `ö` in `evince` works, too.

Comment: @Ingmar My non-minimal, real-world LaTeX document involves T1 encoding anyway, and highlighting with `\hl` is only for debugging/commentary purposes of the draft version. So I wouldn't be particularly bothered by `Str¨ome` within the scope of `\hl`. I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by a sacrificial character such as `!`.