# pdfx causes soul to stop working

Tags: soul, pdfx

I noticed that adding `pdfx` package to my document stopped the `soul` package from highlighting the text in yellow.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}  % comment this out

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soulutf8}

\begin{document}

\hl{TODO}

\end{document}
```

The example above does not report any errors, but results in non-highlighted text, as shown below. Removing the `pdfx` package reverts everything to normal behavior.

[image: actual result]

The order of the packages does not seem to have an immediate effect.

Comment: I didn't encounter any problem when compiling with `pdflatex` (TeXLive 2018). To help you, we need to know the exact error message or the `log` file.

Comment: What is your TeX-engine? Compiling with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX is creating a problem. It needs -shell-escape option in the command.

Comment: PDF Engine: `pdflatex -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

TeXLive version: `texlive-bin 2019.51075-4`

Comment: I uploaded the log file here: https://pastebin.com/2FYtFWtm, and there are not error messages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to a long-standing incompability of soul with xcolor (which is loaded by pdfx). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48502/2388

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}  % comment this out

%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\SOUL@ulunderline}{\dimen@}{\SOUL@dimen}{}{}
\patchcmd{\SOUL@ulunderline}{\dimen@}{\SOUL@dimen}{}{}
\patchcmd{\SOUL@ulunderline}{\dimen@}{\SOUL@dimen}{}{}
\newdimen\SOUL@dimen
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\hl{TODO}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can we fix this in souldutf8 at least?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sure.

Comment: https://github.com/drehscheibe/soul/issues/1