# using latex3 scratch variable

Tags: latex3, variable

`LaTeX3` provides `tmpa` and `tmpb` scratch variables for many different types. As documented, they may be overwritten by other non-kernel code and so should only be used for short-term storage.

What is exactly short-term storage ?

I would say "a group with only kernel, private code, and no third party code whether explicit or not". This seems a serious limitation for the usage of such variables.

Comment: What do you mean by "serious limitation"? It is the same as with every public scratch variable, e.g. \box 0 or \@tempskipa or \dimen@ (where the wrong use lead to an incompability between xcolor and soul https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48502/2388).

Answer (score 11):

The scratch variables are safe if you have no third-party code between setting and usage. As the core of `expl3` does not use these variables at all, you can have basic functions intervening without risk.

Personally, I tend to think of the general scratch variables as mainly aimed at use in *ad hoc* code in documents. They are also useful for genuinely one-off operations during package loading. Anything that is used repeatedly in a package is likely better using a private scratch variable.