# \hl does not cover the entire text

Tags: tables, color

I am attempting to use soul and xcolor to highlight some of my text but as you can see in the image it does not seem to cover the whole text.

[image]

The line is `Service agents must be able to \hl{\mbox{create}} an account`

If I try to remove mbox so it becomes `Service agents must be able to \hl{create} an account` it will look like this:
[image]

How can I fix this so it covers the entire text?

Document:

```
  
%Preamble
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{soul}

% Main.tex
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{report}
\input{Setup/Statics.tex}
\input{Setup/Preamble.tex}
\input{Setup/Settings.tex}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{Chapters/06_Design}
\clearpage 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\printbibliography[title={Bibliography}]
\clearpage 
\appendix
\input{Backmatter/Appendix.tex}
\cleartoleftpage

\end{document}

% Inside Design document
\begin{longtable}{|p{1cm}|p{4cm}|p{10cm}|}
    \caption{Noun and verb analysis} 
\hline
ID            & Requirement                          & Description                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \hline
\textbf{FR1}  & Create account                       & Service agents must be able to \hl{create} an account                                                                                                                               \\ \hline
\end{longtable}


%Settings.tex
% Colours! 
\newcommand{\targetcolourmodel}{cmyk} 
\selectcolormodel{\targetcolourmodel}

\definecolor{dtured}    {rgb/cmyk}{0.6,0,0 / 0,0.91,0.72,0.23}
\definecolor{blue}      {rgb/cmyk}{0.1843,0.2431,0.9176 / 0.88,0.76,0,0}
\definecolor{brightgreen}{rgb/cmyk}{0.1216,0.8157,0.5098 / 0.69,0,0.66,0}
\definecolor{navyblue}  {rgb/cmyk}{0.0118,0.0588,0.3098 / 1,0.9,0,0.6}
\definecolor{yellow}    {rgb/cmyk}{0.9647,0.8157,0.3019 / 0.05,0.17,0.82,0}
\definecolor{orange}    {rgb/cmyk}{0.9882,0.4627,0.2039 / 0,0.65,0.86,0}
\definecolor{pink}      {rgb/cmyk}{0.9686,0.7333,0.6941 / 0,0.35,0.26,0}
\definecolor{grey}      {rgb/cmyk}{0.8549,0.8549,0.8549 / 0,0,0,0.2}
\definecolor{red}       {rgb/cmyk}{0.9098,0.2471,0.2824 / 0,0.86,0.65,0}
\definecolor{green}     {rgb/cmyk}{0,0.5333,0.2078 / 0.89,0.05,1,0.17}
\definecolor{purple}    {rgb/cmyk}{0.4745,0.1373,0.5569 / 0.67,0.96,0,0}

\definecolor{verde}     {rgb}{0.25,0.5,0.35}
\definecolor{jpurple}   {rgb}{0.5,0,0.35}
\definecolor{darkgreen} {rgb}{0.0, 0.2, 0.13}

\colorlet{frontbackcolor}{blue}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces this problem.

Comment: I have tried to add as much code that I think is relevant to the problem and should reproduce the problem. Please let me know if this is not enough

Comment: Well, the MWE should be compilable. I think you should load packages after loading the document class (which you probably do), the color defintions should come before you actually use them, and also you should use `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. As it stands now, the code you provided is rather a bunch of unconnected snippets.

Comment: This problem is known and [has been solved here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48502/47927).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs due to an incompatibility between older version of the `soul` and the `xcolor` package [as described here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48502/47927). The problem can be solved by updating the relevant packages to the latest version.

Alternatively, you can add the following code right after having loaded the `soul` package:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\SOUL@ulunderline}{\dimen@}{\SOUL@dimen}{}{}
\patchcmd{\SOUL@ulunderline}{\dimen@}{\SOUL@dimen}{}{}
\patchcmd{\SOUL@ulunderline}{\dimen@}{\SOUL@dimen}{}{}
\newdimen\SOUL@dimen
\makeatother
```

As for your code, note that you need to add `\\` after `\caption{}` inside a `longtable` environment if you want to typeset the caption above the table. So, to provide a full and compilable MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
 
%Preamble
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

%%%%% the following is not needed with an up-to-date version of the `soul` package
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\SOUL@ulunderline}{\dimen@}{\SOUL@dimen}{}{}
\patchcmd{\SOUL@ulunderline}{\dimen@}{\SOUL@dimen}{}{}
\patchcmd{\SOUL@ulunderline}{\dimen@}{\SOUL@dimen}{}{}
\newdimen\SOUL@dimen
\makeatother
%%%%%

% Colours! 
\newcommand{\targetcolourmodel}{cmyk} 
\selectcolormodel{\targetcolourmodel}

\definecolor{yellow}    {rgb/cmyk}{0.9647,0.8157,0.3019 / 0.05,0.17,0.82,0}

\begin{document}

% Inside document
\begin{longtable}{|p{1cm}|p{4cm}|p{10cm}|}
\caption{Noun and verb analysis}\\
\hline
ID & Requirement & Description \\ \hline
\textbf{FR1} & Create account & Service agents must be able to \hl{create} an account \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]