# What do \@mkboth and \markboth do?

Tags: latex-base

What do the toc related commands `\@mkboth` and `\markboth` do?

Comment: It is mostly the same as `\markboth`, the kernel docs suggest class and package writers sometimes use `\@mkboth` instead as then certain packages can redefine it to do nothing. See `texdoc source2e`

Comment: Fair enough. I now edited the question to ask for `\markboth` as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is the definition of `\markboth` from the [LaTeX kernel](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx):

```
\def\markboth#1#2{%
  \begingroup
    \let\label\relax \let\index\relax \let\glossary\relax
    \unrestored@protected@xdef\@themark {{#1}{#2}}%
    \@temptokena \expandafter{\@themark}%
    \mark{\the\@temptokena}%
  \endgroup
  \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi}
```

It takes two arguments, designed to aid in the setting of the headers in `twoside` mode - the first is set as the left page header, while the second ends up in the right page header.

In contrast, `\@mkboth` is used as an internal kernel tool and may take on multiple functions. From [`source2e`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) (section **65.3 marking conventions**, p 310):

> Commands like `\tableofcontents` that should set the marks in some page
>   styles use a `\@mkboth` command, which is `\let` by the pagestyle command
>   (`\ps@...`) to `\markboth` for setting the heading or to `\@gobbletwo` to do nothing.

For example, the `empty` page style (in `latex.ltx`) sets

```
\def\ps@empty{%
  \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo\let\@oddhead\@empty\let\@oddfoot\@empty
  \let\@evenhead\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty}
```

while the `headings` page style (in [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls)) sets

```
\if@twoside
  \def\ps@headings{%
      \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
      \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
      \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
      \let\@mkboth\markboth
      ...
```

Comment: Are `\markboth` and `\@mkboth` thus only intended to be used with `twoside` option?

Comment: @Mappi: No. Their effect will depend on the `twoside` option, but you can use them in both.

Comment: For anybody else who's also wondering what `\unrestored@protected@xdef` does, I asked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408240/functionality-of-unrestoredprotectedxdef) (which was before I got enough reputation to comment everywhere, thus explaining why I didn't just ask in a comment on this answer.)

Comment: @Werner:  OK, but what does the `\temptokena` macro do?

Comment: @Werner:  Never mind, found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88261/71079).

Comment: @Werner:  Now that I think about it, I'm not sure if I completely understand a couple of things.  First, why does `\markboth`'s implementation invoke `\expandafter` with only one argument (`\@themark`, on the line where the result of doing that gets assigned to `\@temptokena`?)  Does `@themark` get expanded once before `\expandafter` sees it?  …

Comment: @Werner:  …Second, I'm a bit perplexed as to how the invocation reading '`\mark{\the\@temptokena}`' would play out.  I understand that `\the\@temptokena` should come out as something like either '`{#1}\number2expanded`' or '`{#1}{#2}`' depending on what the earlier `\expandafter` sees and outputs, but, as far as I understand from [this link](https://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html#mark-rp), doesn't `\mark` only take one argument?  I suppose one could expand both into the same argument slot right after one another, but I'm not sure why one would want to do that, as a user of this command…

Comment: …presumably wants to set more than just one of `\topmark`, `\firstmark`, and `\botmark` when invoking it.  Doing so additionally makes even _less_ sense in the context of why I asked [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408240/71079), where the source I was looking at that initially led me down this rabbit hole passed the _exact same thing_ for _both_ `#1` _and_ `#2`; one would then get the text resulting from the expansion of those identical token streams' contained macros seen twice, right next to each other.  Could you or someone else walk me through what's going on here?

Comment: @RandomDSdevel I am not sure what you mean by `'{#1}\number2expanded'` but the result is always two brace groups. The point is to edef expand everything except page number related commands such as `\label` at the point of the `\markboth` while allowing the other commands to be expanded later when/if the mark is used.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle:  By '`\number2expanded`', I meant a placeholder for the result of expanding the '`{#2}`' in the '`{{#1}{#2}}`' assigned to '`\@themark`' by `\unrestored@protected@xdef`' in the implementation of '`\markboth`.'  Other than that, what you say makes sense…except I'm still a bit confused by the apparent macro parameter/argument arity mismatches that pop out at me in the invocations of '`\expandafter`' and '`\mark`' in that same code.

Comment: @RandomDSdevel you seem to be asking questions about how \markboth works internally as comments on an existing question about what it does as a user command, which isn't really the way the site is supposed to work, but what you seem to be missing is that in latex `\mark` is always used as `\mark{{a}{b}}` with two brace groups

Comment: @DavidCarlisle:  Oh.  That wasn't exactly clear from [this other documentation I found](https://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html#mark-rp).  Am I to take it that the first argument is for setting `\firsmark` and the second is for setting `\botmark`, then?

Comment: no `\firatmark` and `\botmark` are primitives so they will get the contents of `\mark` (both groups) but the latex macros `\@leftmark` and `\@rightmark` extract the first or second group respectively

Comment: @RandomDSdevel that page is documenting plain tex so it is not that it isn't clear about latex, it doesn't attempt to document latex at all.

Comment: @Symbol1:  I evidently made a mistake, as an frequent reader but only rarely a poster on this site, in not entering what I wrote under the category that you prefer. But it ought to be said that I wrote, with the help of Werner, would indeed answer the question, as it suggests a functional interaction of \@mkboth and \markboth, and its consequence, without subjecting the hypothesized interaction to Werner's superior scrutinyt. I now see that what I wrote is too long for a comment.  I request that you allow Werner to respond for benefit of the original writer and others.

Comment: @Louis: I did read your post, but it doesn't make sense to me. Perhaps because I didn't read as much into "should" as you did...

Comment: @Werner: I could try to clarify first by saying that I don't know what they meant by "should."  That aside, there are three problems posed for understanding what goes on between \@mxboth and \markboth. (1) Does “Contents” gets stored in \@mkboth? (2) By virtue of \let\@mkboth\markboth, is "Contents" passed to \rightmark or \leftmark in the definitions of \oddhead and \evenhead, thence to become a header?

Comment: @Werner:  (3) The answer to (2) seems to turn on whether \let establishes a symmetric relations between its arguments.  Knuth suggests it is when defining \let with `=' (TeXbook, 206), but his prose and commentary seem to suggest that it is asymmetric: it assigns the current value of the second argument to the first, but does not assign the first to the second.  I thought from your quotation of the same code lines that I've been studying that you might know.

Comment: @Louis: `\let\cmdA\cmdB` copies the current version of `\cmdB` to `\cmdA`, overwriting whatever `\cmdA` used to contain. The use of `=` is optional.

Comment: @Werner:  That's exactly how I've seen it described (Kopka and Daly, 440), which is to say that the relation is asymmetric, hence `=' is not used in its mathematical sense.  (The equality relation is reflexive, symmetrical, and transitive.) If so, how could `\@mkboth` at beginning of a document, before any marks are set by section commands, acquire 'Contents,' or any token list, from `\markboth,` which would seem to be empty there?  Perhaps there's some other that way that `\tableofcontents' populates `\markboth`? But then what's `\let\@mkboth\markboth' doing in your quote from article.cls?

Comment: @Louis: Note that adding `\let\@mkboth\markboth` as part of `\tableofcontents` doesn't mean the assignment to `\@mkboth` happens when `\tableofcontents` is defined (as part of the document class, or possible in the preamble with other package loading, like [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft)). Instead, that assignment only occurs when `\tableofcontents` is invoked/called/executed. This is referred to as expansion. This is unlike other programming languages where variable definitions are set at the time of definition.

Comment: @Werner:  I understand.  I was referring to LaTeX processing when it comes to `table of contents` on the first or other early page, at which point nothing has been written to `\markboth' because no sectioning command has been issued.  How then does anything get copied to `\@mkboth`?

Comment: @Louis: The ToC is set as a `\section*` or `\chapter*`, depending on the document class.

Comment: @Werner:  Thanks. This is revelatory! I see it in classes.dtx and article.cls, with `\section*` sending 'Contents' formatted to \@mkboth, which could begin a path to a header:  to `\markboth` by operation of `\let`, in oneside thence to `\firstmark`, by expansion to `\rightmark`, by expansion to `\oddhead`.  But that path is open only if `\let` is symmetric. Only then does `\markboth` get 'Contents.'  The authors of classes.dtx suggest this path by 'we \`let  \@mkboth' to `\markboth`, 'to' suggesting 'equate to.' Yet commentary contradicts this interpretation of symmetry. I'm stumped.

Comment: @Louis: I suggest you create a small example, something with just one section and a ToC inside an `article`, and add `\tracingmacros1` just before `\tableofcontents`. Then you can look in the resulting `.log` how the macro execution works, step-by-step, and figure out where assignments are made and what values they contain. That would be a starting point for a in-depth view on the macro process. [Latex `\tracing` commands list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60491/5764)

Comment: @Werner: I followed those steps, generating the large .log file, and searched for all the code I've mentioned, but did not find anything seeming to be directly on point.  I don't know to which macro's execution you refer. I'm trying to imagine an explanation from the logic of the code.