# Functionality of `\unrestored@protected@xdef`?

Tags: macros

So, I was reading `texdoc tamethebeast` ([*Taming the BeaST:  The B to X of BibTeX*](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf)) when I came across a macro I'd never seen before in its discussion of the implementation of `\thebibliography`; this was the macro `\@mkboth`.  [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198691/71079) to the question ['What do \@mkboth and \markboth do?'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198676/what-do-mkboth-and-markboth-do) explains what that does, but I then came across *another* macro inside *that* command's definition that I've *also* never seen before; *that* macro was `\unrestored@protected@xdef`.  Neither the [*LaTeX2e unofficial reference manual (August 2017)*](http://tug.org/texinfohtml/latex2e.html) nor [this web listing documenting *TeX Primitive Control Sequences*](https://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html) contains any mention of its function.  That leads me to wonder what it does, so can anyone answer that and/or point me toward a reference that *does* explain how it works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command is about defining macros with expansion. The TeX primitive `\edef` defines a macro like `\def`, but it expands the definition text. For example:

```
\def\Who{World}
\edef\Hello{Hello \Who}
```

The macro `\Who` is expanded and the definition text of `\Hello` is `Hello World`.

`\xdef` is just the global variant of `\edef`: `\xdef` = `\global\edef`.

In many circumstances, the hard expansion by `\edef` or `\xdef` will fail, if fragile macros are expanded. For example, the following macro is not robust:

```
\def\FragileMacro{%
  \def\MyMacro{...}%
  ...
}
```

If `\FragileMacro` is used inside `\edef` or `\xdef`, then `\def` is not an expandable token and is just kept without further processing, i.e. it does not define anything. Then `\MyMacro` is tried to be expanded. If it is undefined, then an error message because of an undefined command is thrown. Or, it expands to some non-active characters. Then, a later execution of `\FragileMacro` will fail, because `\def` cannot define non-active characters.

The LaTeX way is protection:

- `\protect` before a fragile macro prevents its expansion.
- Macros can be defined as robust command via `\DeclareRobustCommand`. It smuggles `\protect` before an internal macro that contains the possibly fragile command text.

There are several problematic contexts, e.g. displaying something in the .log file/console, writing to a file, or in this case expansion by `\edef` or `\xdef`. The correct definition of `\protect` depends on these contexts.
In the case of `\edef` or `\xdef` it is `\@unexpandable@protect`:

```
\def\@unexpandable@protect{\noexpand\protect\noexpand}
```

Then

```
\let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
\edef\FooBar{\protect\FragileCommand}
```

becomes after the first expansion of `\protect` to

```
\edef\FooBar{\noexpand\protect\noexpand\FragileCommand}
```

`\noexpand` prevents the expansion of the next token, and the definition
is equivalent to

```
\def\FooBar{\protect\FragileCommand}
```

`\protect` is retained and `\FragileCommand` is prevented from expansion.

The internal LaTeX macros `\@protected@edef` and `\@protected@xdef` are the LaTeX counterparts for plain TeX's `\edef` and `\xdef`:

```
\def\protected@edef{%
   \let\@@protect\protect
   \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
   \afterassignment\restore@protect
   \edef
}
\def\protected@xdef{%
   \let\@@protect\protect
   \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
   \afterassignment\restore@protect
   \xdef
}
```

First `\@@protect` gets the current meaning of `\protect`. Then `\protect` is redefined according to the context (expanded definition). `\protect` gets the meaning of `\@unexpandable@protect`. The redefinition of `\protect` is reverted by `\afterassignment`. It calls `\restore@protect` right after the next assignment that is `\edef` or `\xdef`. `\restore@protect` restores the definition of `\protect` with the previously defined `\@@protect`:

```
\def\restore@protect{\let\protect\@@protect}
```

The version `\unrestored@protected@xdef` is an optimized version of `\@protected@edef` that still redefines `\protect`, but leaves out the restoration of `\protect`:

```
\def\unrestored@protected@xdef{%
   \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
   \xdef
}
```

The macro definition is smaller and faster, it avoids a macro expansion and two assignments. But, it can be only used in special circumstances, typically at the end of a group:

```
\begingroup
  ...
  \@unrestored@protected@xdef\FooBar{\protect\FragileMacro}%
\endgroup
```

At the end of the group, any local changes (here, the redefinition of `\protect`) is reverted anyway. The explicit restoration of `\protect` is not needed.

Typical use cases in `latex.ltx`:

```
\def\@xfootnote[#1]{%
   \begingroup
     \csname c@\@mpfn\endcsname #1\relax
     \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}%
   \endgroup
   \@footnotemark\@footnotetext
}
\def\@xfootnotemark[#1]{%
   \begingroup
      \c@footnote #1\relax
      \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thefootnote}%
   \endgroup
   \@footnotemark
}
\def\@xfootnotenext[#1]{%
  \begingroup
     \csname c@\@mpfn\endcsname #1\relax
     \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}%
  \endgroup
  \@footnotetext
}
```

The group can also be seen in `\markboth`:

```
\def\markboth#1#2{%
  \begingroup
    \let\label\relax \let\index\relax \let\glossary\relax
    \unrestored@protected@xdef\@themark {{#1}{#2}}%
    \@temptokena \expandafter{\@themark}%
    \mark{\the\@temptokena}%
  \endgroup
  \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}
```

The group seems to be missing in `\@markright`:

```
\def\@markright#1#2#3{\@temptokena {#1}%
  \unrestored@protected@xdef\@themark{{\the\@temptokena}{#3}}%
}
```

But `\@markright` itself is called inside a group:

```
\def\markright#1{%
  \begingroup
    \let\label\relax \let\index\relax \let\glossary\relax
    \expandafter\@markright\@themark {#1}%
    \@temptokena \expandafter{\@themark}%
    \mark{\the\@temptokena}%
  \endgroup
  \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}
```

After the definition of `\@themark` by `\@markright`, the new contents for the marks register needs to be added to `\mark`. However, `\mark` again would expand the argument (`\@themark` is already expanded by `\@unrestored@protected@xdef`). Therefore, a scratch token register `\@temptokena` is used as trick. `\the` before a token register expands the token register only once, the contents are not expanded further.

Comment: You left out a backtick in '…but leaves out the restoration of `\protect:  …'  (I'd fix it myself, but the StackExchange software doesn't allow edit suggestions smaller than…4 characters, IIRC, was it…?

Comment: What does the `\@temptokena` inside `\markboth`'s definition do?  I haven't seen a definition for it anywhere, either…

Comment: Wait, never mind on that second comment; I should _probably_ post that on the page for the question about `\markboth` that I referenced in _my_ question.

Comment: OK, asked there [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198676/what-do-mkboth-and-markboth-do#comment1018561_198691), thus following through on my own suggestion to myself and rendering the issue dealt with.

Comment: @RandomDSdevel Thanks, typo fixed. The updated answer also shortly explains the usage of the token register `\@temptokena` in `\markright` (same as in `\markboth`).

Comment: I have one or two more questions about how exactly `\markboth`'s implementation works even after this (inside `\markboth`'s LaTeX-internal counterpart was where I first saw `\unrestored@protected@xdef`, after all,) but I'm going to leave them as comments on the question page for ['What do \@mkboth and \markboth do?'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198676/what-do-mkboth-and-markboth-do).