# Page counter is reset when highlighting long text using sethlcolor from soul package

Tags: page-numbering, highlighting, soul

I encounter a similar problem like this [TeX question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437606/what-can-cause-page-counter-to-reset-without-using-setcounter) or [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925927/highlighting-text-affecting-page-numbers-in-latex). However, I open a new question because the examples given by the previous ones were not suited to highlight the potential problems, as the lack of answers suggest.

I found that using the package `soul` (or `soulutf8`) to highlight text causes the reset of page numbering when the highlighted text is too long.
I give a minimal working example below using `lipsum` text. In the second page, the highlighted text reset the page number to 0.

Furthermore, I found out that reducing the highlighted zone (by removing the last highlighted paragraph for example) solves the problem.
So a potential solution is to highlight each paragraph calling again the `\hlyellow` macro.
This works but it is cumbersome when one's need to highlight big pieces of text.
Is highlighting several pages with one command possible ? If so, how the given example should be adapted, please ?

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{xcolor}       % Coloured text etc.
\usepackage{soul}             % To easily highlight text
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Highlight text with predefined colors
\newcommand{\hlyellow}[1]{{\sethlcolor{yellow}\hl{#1}}}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Minimum working example}
\lipsum[1]

\section{First section}
\lipsum[2-4]

\hlyellow{Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor
lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Do-
nec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare
odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras
nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis partu-
rient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper
vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at, tin-
cidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy pellen-
tesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin fermentum massa ac quam. Sed
diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia. Nam ip-
sum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat
magna. Nunc eleifend consequat lorem. Sed lacinia nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque
tincidunt purus vel magna. Integer non enim. Praesent euismod nunc eu purus. Do-
nec bibendum quam in tellus. Nullam cursus pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi. Nam
vulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulum pellentesque felis eu massa.

Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor
lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Do-
nec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare
odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras
nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis partu-
rient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper
vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at, tin-
cidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy pellen-
tesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin fermentum massa ac quam. Sed
diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia. Nam ip-
sum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat
magna. Nunc eleifend consequat lorem. Sed lacinia nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque
tincidunt purus vel magna. Integer non enim. Praesent euismod nunc eu purus. Do-
nec bibendum quam in tellus. Nullam cursus pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi. Nam
vulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulum pellentesque felis eu massa.

Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor
lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Do-
nec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare
odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras
nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis partu-
rient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper
vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at, tin-
cidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy pellen-
tesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin fermentum massa ac quam. Sed
diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia. Nam ip-
sum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat
magna. Nunc eleifend consequat lorem. Sed lacinia nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque
tincidunt purus vel magna. Integer non enim. Praesent euismod nunc eu purus. Do-
nec bibendum quam in tellus. Nullam cursus pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi. Nam
vulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulum pellentesque felis eu massa.
}

\section{Second section}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use paragraph breaks inside a \hl command.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I didn't realize such pratice was so doomed. I'll split the highlighting or maybe just color the text itself.

Comment: I believe this might be the same problem as reported in [bug with page numbers when using soul package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25250/bug-with-page-numbers-when-using-soul-package)