# Figure touching the top or bottom of page causes page numbering to reset to zero?

Tags: page-numbering, soul

I am experiencing this weird bug where if a figure touches the top or bottom of a page, is the page numbering reset to zero on that page.

I haven't been able to make a minimal example showing the effect as it seems to be very situational.
But I have attached a picture of the resulting pages at the bottom of this post.
(Don't mind the blurred out text.)

What could cause this weird behaviour, is it a bug or intended?
If it is a bug, where can I report it?
And what can I do about it? (Besides changing picture sizes and moving text around by hand.)

---

Edit:
I have made the smallest version of the file I can and attached it here:
The picture used is also attached.
The first page is indexed as page number 0, when it should be 1.

Notice that I use a non-standard header, footer and margin size.
I don't think this should influence that the bug can appear. 
The highlight of the text in the second section is necessary to show the bug, I am not sure why.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, includefoot, footskip=30pt, includehead, headsep=20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}
\section{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}

\subsection{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sollicitudin pulvinar sapien in tempus.
\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{tree.png}
    \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sollicitudin pulvinar sapien in tempus.}
    \label{fig_areasOfWork}
\end{figure}

\section{Next section}
Lorem ipsum dolor
\hl{
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sollicitudin pulvinar sapien in tempus.

Etiam non orci ut dolor efficitur sodales. Mauris egestas sapien nunc, in facilisis mauris elementum ac.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: The problem persists if you remove the `\\ \\ \\ […] \\` and replace the figure with `\vspace{20cm}, so this appears to have little to do with the `figure` and everything to do with a bug in `soul`. I think [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25250/156366) is about the same problem.

Comment: There are actually [quite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437606/what-can-cause-page-counter-to-reset-without-using-setcounter) [a](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/524669/156366) [few](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28925927/9780550) unanswered questions about this…

Comment: I added [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/545515/156366) to the aforementioned question that applies to your situation as well.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the helps guys.