# `soul` and `soulpos` cause page restart if used heavily

Tags: page-numbering, highlighting, soul

I use lots of highlights as it is used to mark my revision from each version before I gave to my lecturer. When I highlight lots of texts, I found out that sometimes page restarted in the middle.

After an hour of stress, I found the cause, that is heavy use of highlight as mentioned [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=117985#p117985). That page mention `soul`, but I use `soulpos`. It seems that both packages got the same bug.

Below is my code to make the highlight:

```tex
\usepackage{soulpos}
\ulposdef{\hly}{%
  \mbox{%
    \color{yellow}%
    \rule[-.8ex]{\ulwidth}{11pt}%
    \tolerance=1%
    \emergencystretch=\maxdimen}}
```

Any solution? Why this is happening? Can this kind of bug be fixed? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

From the comment section, this bug for soul is discussed and solved [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/545515/230830). Sadly, `soulpos` did not use `\countdef` and the same fix can't be used.

**EDIT after more testing:**

Okay, now I become more confused:

1. With separate cls, soulpos did not get this problem. See [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/kgpbrrjmkxhr)
2. With no separate cls, soulpos can't solve even with the minus. See [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/brbstvtynhxw)

This (No 2) got wrong page numbering, but not if I use .cls (see No 1)

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soulpos}

\makeatletter
\newcount\SOUL@minus
% \newcount\SOULPOS@minus
\makeatother

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\ulposdef{\hly}{%
  \mbox{%
    \color{yellow}%
    \rule[-.8ex]{\ulwidth}{11pt}%
    \tolerance=1%
    \emergencystretch=\maxdimen}}
 
\begin{document}

\Blindtext[4]
\blindtext
\hl{Closing words

New paragraph!}

\clearpage

\Blindtext[4]
\blindtext
\hly{Closing words

New paragraph!}

\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry but neither your question nor the page you link too contains any useful information. You only claim that soul is doing something without any proof or code. But if you want to do lots of highlighting, I recommend to switch to lualatex and lua-ul. That is much more stable than soul.

Comment: As @UlrikeFischer said, switch to lua. You can even make lua-ul backwards compatible to soul: `\usepackage[soul]{lua-ul}`

Comment: Does the answers at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25250/bug-with-page-numbers-when-using-soul-package helps you?

Comment: `\mbox{%
    \color{yellow}%
    \rule[-.8ex]{\ulwidth}{11pt}%
    \tolerance=1%
    \emergencystretch=\maxdimen`  makes  yellow rule but why are you setting `\tolerance=` and `\emergencystretch` in an `\mbox` ?????

Comment: @quark67 thanks a lot, that was the point of my question. Sadly, the fix described there only works for `soul`. Is a fix possible for `soulpos`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that is required in my document. Remove that line will cause all highlight to be slightly mismatched with other text.

Comment: @MuhammadYasirroni those settings in an mbox do nothing at all. but as you have posted no code showing your problem it will not be possible to answer your question

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, based on @quark67 comment, I found out that using this combo solve my issue. I haven't fully tested it, but it works for now.

```tex
\usepackage{soulpos}
\newcount\SOUL@minus
```

**EDIT after more testing:**

Okay, now I become more confused:

1. With separate cls, soulpos did not get this problem. See [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/kgpbrrjmkxhr)
2. With no separate cls, soulpos can't solve even with the minus. See [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/brbstvtynhxw)

Comment: do you really need `SOULPOS@minus` ? I do not see any use of that name in the package.  `SOUL@minus` is for a soul package bug as quark67 commented

Comment: we have just adopted `soul` and pushed a fix for SOUL@minus to ctan

Comment: @DavidCarlisle After more testing with cleaned artifact, only `\newcount\SOUL@minus` seems works and `\newcount\SOULPOS@minus` seems do nothing. Thanks.

Comment: ok as I expected the updated soul and soulutf8 packages should be in texlive in a day or so