# How to remove excess whitespace on the first page?

Tags: white-space

The following MWE closely reproduces a LaTeX file I created. I'm using [@egreg's solution to my question about programatically creating dummy text.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40812/3406)

The issue is that the quoted section on the second page is pushed to
the second page. I suppose this is because of the altered definition
of the `quoting` environment that I used, namely

```
\tcolorboxenvironment{quoting}{code={\mbox{}},nobeforeafter,boxrule=2pt,sharp corners,breakable,skin=enhanced,colback=white}
```

However, I've been using that definition of quoting in a style file
for some time, and it's mostly worked for me. And it's probably used
in a number of existing documents. So I'd like to keep it as it is.

I have the following questions.

1) First, a minor one. I am correct to think that using `vskip=10in`
in the following line was an error, in the sense that it gets
overwritten by the new definition of quoting?

```
\usepackage[vskip=10in]{quoting}
```

I'm only using the quoting environment from the quoting package, as
shown below, nothing else.

If this the case, I'll remove `vskip=10in` from that package
declaration.

2) My main question is whether there is a graceful way to avoid having
a large amount of empty space at the bottom of the first page.

I suppose this is being caused by the `\mbox{}` in the
`\tcolorboxenvironment` declaration.

I was thinking that I could just leave the changed definition of quoting in the preamble as it is, but temporarily alter the definition in such a way as to allow that box on the second page to move to the first page. Is that possible? Or is there a better way to do it?

```
    \documentclass[12pt, sections, headheight=30pt, headinclude, 
    firstfoot=false, enlargefirstpage=true, foldmarks=false,
    foldmarks=blmtP, fromalign=center, fromphone, fromemail, version=last,
    backaddress=false, subject=titled]{scrlttr2}

    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage[vskip=10in]{quoting}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{fouriernc}
    \tcolorboxenvironment{quoting}{code={\mbox{}},nobeforeafter,boxrule=2pt,sharp corners,breakable,skin=enhanced,colback=white}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\dummy}{m m m}
  {
   \prg_replicate:nn { #3 }
     {
      \prg_replicate:nn { #2 } { #1 \hfill } \dummy_endline:
     }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \dummy_endline:
  { { \parfillskip=0pt\par } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Address}
\renewcommand{\phonename}{Landline}
\renewcommand{\mobilephonename}{Mobile}
\setkomavar{frommobilephone}{Mobile}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{Email}
\setkomavar{signature}{(\usekomavar{fromname})}
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
    \textbf{\jobname.tex} \input{"| hg log -v -l 1 \jobname.tex --template '{node}  {date|isodate}'"}
    \ifhmode \\ \fi
    {\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont
    \hspace{\textwidth}
    \usekomavar{fromname}\\
    \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
    \usekomavar*{mobilephoneseparator}\usekomavar{mobilephoneseparator}\usekomavar{frommobilephone}\\
    \usekomavar*{emailseparator}\usekomavar{emailseparator}\usekomavar{fromemail}
    }
  }%
}

\makeatletter
\@addtoplength{firstheadvpos}{30pt}
\@addtoplength{toaddrvpos}{40pt}
\@addtoplength{refvpos}{10pt}
\@addtoplength{sigbeforevskip}{20pt}
\makeatletter\@setplength{sigindent}{0.5\linewidth}\makeatother
\makeatother

\def\today{20th February, 2019}
\begin{letter}{
    Someone\\
    Company\\
    Building\\
    Street\\
    City
  }

  \opening{Hi}

  \dummy{HelloWorld!}{3}{5}
  \begin{quoting}
    \dummy{HelloWorld!}{3}{3}
  \end{quoting}

  \dummy{HelloWorld!}{3}{3}

  \begin{quoting}
    \begin{tabular}{p{4.5in}r}
      \textbf{\dummy{HelloWorld!}{3}{1}  }  & \\
      \dummy{HelloWorld!}{3}{2}             & \dummy{HelloWorld!}{1}{1}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{quoting}

\closing{Yours Sincerely,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda Well, I lose my before and after spacing.

Comment: Why do you need `code={\mbox{}}` ?

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda Without it, I get no spacing before my quoting box. I'm pretty someone on the site suggested it. I would never have thought of that on my own. It's possible I just copied it from somewhere.

Comment: That is because you are adding `nobeforeafter`

Comment: So try `\tcolorboxenvironment{quoting}{boxrule=2pt,sharp corners,breakable,skin=enhanced,colback=white}`

Comment: Yes, I see the documentation says: "Abbreviation for clearing the keys before and after. The colored box is not put into a paragraph and there is no space before or after the box." So is that a reasonable definition to use?

Comment: I'm a bit concerned about altering existing documents, though.

Comment: Create two version of your quoting box with different names. One for your old document and one for your  new documents

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda Yes, that's a good solution. Obvious, but I didn't think of it.

Comment: Me two I didn't think of it the first time I had a similar problem and fortunately I found  someone tin this site who gave me  the solution

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda So is my problem, in your opinion, that I was using a bad redefinition of the quoting environment?

Comment: I think that if you want just to make some space around your box `\code={\mbox{}}` is not the ideal solution.

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda You're probably right. Feel free to write an answer if you wish.

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda If you have a better option with respect to creating some space around these boxes, please do mention it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90175/discussion-between-hafid-boukhoulda-and-faheem-mitha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to remove `code={\mbox{}}` and `nobeforeafter` from the option list passed to the `\tcolorbox` definition:

```
\documentclass[12pt, sections, headheight=30pt, headinclude, 
    firstfoot=false, enlargefirstpage=true, foldmarks=false,
    foldmarks=blmtP, fromalign=center, fromphone, fromemail, version=last,
    backaddress=false, subject=titled]{scrlttr2}

    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage[vskip=10in]{quoting}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{fouriernc}
    \tcolorboxenvironment{quoting}{
        %code={\mbox{}},nobeforeafter,

        before skip=\baselineskip, % or before skip = 1cm or something else

        boxrule=2pt,sharp corners,breakable,skin=enhanced,colback=white}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\dummy}{m m m}
  {
   \prg_replicate:nn { #3 }
     {
      \prg_replicate:nn { #2 } { #1 \hfill } \dummy_endline:
     }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \dummy_endline:
  { { \parfillskip=0pt\par } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Address}
\renewcommand{\phonename}{Landline}
\renewcommand{\mobilephonename}{Mobile}
\setkomavar{frommobilephone}{Mobile}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{Email}
\setkomavar{signature}{(\usekomavar{fromname})}
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
    \textbf{\jobname.tex} \input{"| hg log -v -l 1 \jobname.tex --template '{node}  {date|isodate}'"}
    \ifhmode \\ \fi
    {\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont
    \hspace{\textwidth}
    \usekomavar{fromname}\\
    \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
    \usekomavar*{mobilephoneseparator}\usekomavar{mobilephoneseparator}\usekomavar{frommobilephone}\\
    \usekomavar*{emailseparator}\usekomavar{emailseparator}\usekomavar{fromemail}
    }
  }%
}

\makeatletter
\@addtoplength{firstheadvpos}{30pt}
\@addtoplength{toaddrvpos}{40pt}
\@addtoplength{refvpos}{10pt}
\@addtoplength{sigbeforevskip}{20pt}
\makeatletter\@setplength{sigindent}{0.5\linewidth}\makeatother
\makeatother

\def\today{20th February, 2019}
\begin{letter}{
    Someone\\
    Company\\
    Building\\
    Street\\
    City
  }

  \opening{Hi}

  \dummy{HelloWorld!}{3}{5}
  \begin{quoting}
    \dummy{HelloWorld!}{3}{3}
  \end{quoting}

  \dummy{HelloWorld!}{3}{3}

  \begin{quoting}
    \begin{tabular}{p{4.5in}r}
      \textbf{\dummy{HelloWorld!}{3}{1}  }  & \\
      \dummy{HelloWorld!}{3}{2}             & \dummy{HelloWorld!}{1}{1}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{quoting}

\closing{Yours Sincerely,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see you've add some "before skip". Would also adding some "after skip" be reasonable, or is there some reason to prefer "before skip"?

Comment: @FaheemMitha you can add `after skip` or if the same spaces before and after the boxes are required you can replace `before skip` with `beforeafter skip`

Comment: Yes, `beforeafter skip` seems like a good option. Thank you.